# How can I filter ListView data when typing on EditText in android

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` and a `EditText`. How can I filter ListView data when typing on `EditText`?

Comment: Think my solution to this might be just what you are looking for!

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/answer-to-making-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android/1737042#1737042>

Comment: Johe, 
Have a look here, explanation is VERY clear.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901020/android-xml-list-view-with-filter/2282012#2282012

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1737042/523325) for a nice solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Add `TextWatcher` to `EditText#addTextChangedListener`
2. In  `onTextChanged` add or remove items from your `ListView`'s adapter. If you are subclassing `ArrayAdapter` it would have `add` and `remove` methods

Answer (score 26):

Yes you can, just implement this code. Use the following code to implement search and filter list in android:

**SearchAndFilterList.java**

```
public class SearchAndFilterList extends Activity {

    private ListView mSearchNFilterLv;

    private EditText mSearchEdt;

    private ArrayList<String> mStringList;

    private ValueAdapter valueAdapter;

    private TextWatcher mSearchTw;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_and_filter_list);

        initUI();

        initData();

        valueAdapter=new ValueAdapter(mStringList,this);

        mSearchNFilterLv.setAdapter(valueAdapter);

        mSearchEdt.addTextChangedListener(mSearchTw);


    }
    private void initData() {

        mStringList=new ArrayList<String>();

        mStringList.add("one");

        mStringList.add("two");

        mStringList.add("three");

        mStringList.add("four");

        mStringList.add("five");

        mStringList.add("six");

        mStringList.add("seven");

        mStringList.add("eight");

        mStringList.add("nine");

        mStringList.add("ten");

        mStringList.add("eleven");

        mStringList.add("twelve");

        mStringList.add("thirteen");

        mStringList.add("fourteen");

        mSearchTw=new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                valueAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        };

    }

    private void initUI() {

        mSearchNFilterLv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        mSearchEdt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
    }

}
```

Custom Value adapter:
**ValueAdapter.java**

```
public class ValueAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

private ArrayList<String> mStringList;

private ArrayList<String> mStringFilterList;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private ValueFilter valueFilter;

public ValueAdapter(ArrayList<String> mStringList,Context context) {

    this.mStringList=mStringList;

    this.mStringFilterList=mStringList;

    mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

    getFilter();
}

//How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mStringList.size();
}

//Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return mStringList.get(position);
}

//Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list.
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

//Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the data set.
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder viewHolder;

    if(convertView==null) {

        viewHolder=new Holder();

        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

        viewHolder.nameTv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_listitem);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{

        viewHolder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
    }

        viewHolder.nameTv.setText(mStringList.get(position).toString());

        return convertView;
}

private class  Holder{

    TextView nameTv;
}

//Returns a filter that can be used to constrain data with a filtering pattern.
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if(valueFilter==null) {

        valueFilter=new ValueFilter();
    }

    return valueFilter;
}


private class ValueFilter extends Filter {


    //Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the constraint.
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();

        if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){

            ArrayList<String> filterList=new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i<mStringFilterList.size();i++){

                if(mStringFilterList.get(i).contains(constraint)) {

                    filterList.add(mStringFilterList.get(i));

                }
            }


            results.count=filterList.size();

            results.values=filterList;

        }else{

            results.count=mStringFilterList.size();

            results.values=mStringFilterList;

        }

        return results;
    }


    //Invoked in the UI thread to publish the filtering results in the user interface.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {

        mStringList=(ArrayList<String>) results.values;

        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

}
```

activity_search_and_filter_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_search"
        tools:context=".SearchAndFilterList"
        android:hint="Enter text to search" />
    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_search"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_listitem"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifext.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.searchandfilterlistview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchAndFilterList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_and_filter_list" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope this code will will helpful to implement custom search and filter listview.

Comment: Call adaptor.getFilter().filter(s) in  afterTextChanged()

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

`addTextChangedListener( TextWatcher watcher )`

to figure out when the textview was changed. I believe it should be called everytime a letter is added or removed.

Then update your list adapter to dislplay the new items by either:

1. creating a new list adapter and populating it with the items that satisfy the filter or
2. having a subclass of the `BaseAdapter` to accept your filter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after it has finished removing the items you no longer want

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Comment: So you mean for the TextView? I'm using EditText. Anyway, I think it's also useful for me! thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Fortunately, EditText is a subclass of TextView and was still relevant. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Search a listview based on input in EditText

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView lv,lv2;
private EditText et;
String listview_array[]={"01634 ABOHAR","080 Bangalore","011 Delhi","Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "1234", "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800", "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};
private ArrayList<String> array_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
int textlength = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView02);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
    int x= lv.getHeaderViewsCount ();
    System.out.println("x========"+x);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (MainActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
        int start, int count, int after)
        {

            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.

        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
        int start, int before, int count)
        {
            textlength = et.getText().length();
            array_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < listview_array.length; i++)
            {
                if (textlength <= listview_array[i].length())
                {

                    String s2= et.getText().toString();
                    if(listview_array[i].toString().contains(et.getText().toString()))
                    {
                        array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
                    }


                }
            }

            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
        }
    });

}
 }
```

For search in custom listview based on class item refer the link [implement search on a custom listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383943/implement-search-on-a-custom-listview/13110015#13110015). Modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Mine was a Custom ListView even after that, the code in onTextChanged() worked well.

Answer (score 0):

when you use custom listView

Adapter :

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> filteredData = new ArrayList<>();

public Adapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") View vi = inflate.inflate(R.layout.ly_items, null);
    try {
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject(list.get(position));
        TextView txtItem = vi.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
        ImageView imgItem = vi.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
        txtItem.setText(js.getString("name") + " - " + js.getInt("number"));
        Picasso.get().load(js.getString("logo_url")).into(imgItem);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return vi;
}

@Override
public void add(@Nullable Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object.toString());
    filteredData.add(object.toString());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}


public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    list.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        list.addAll(filteredData);
    } else {
        for (String wp : filteredData) {

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(wp);
                if (json.getString("name").toLowerCase().contains(charText) || json.getString("number").contains(charText)) {
                    list.add(wp);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And your class:

```
 Adapter adapter;
ListView list;
EditText edtSearch;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

list = findViewById(R.id.list);

edtSearch = findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);

 adapter = new Adapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);


list.setAdapter(adapter);

edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

1) create a custom adapter for your list view and create a removeIfMatch(String s) method:

```
public void removeIfMatch(String s) {
  for item in adapter:
    if item.matches(s) {
       data.removeItem(item);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
       break
    }
}
```

2) create a callback for when the EditText contents change

3) invoke adapter.removeIfMatch(editText.getText())

Comment: What happens if someone over types then hits the backspace key?

Comment: There is already facilities for filters. Your solution alter the datas in your list. Like fiXedd pointed out if you press backspace removed won't come back. You shouldn't reinvent the wheel.