# How to text filter an Android ListView backed by a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, database, listview, filter, android-cursor

I have a ListView that is backed by a SimpleCursorAdapter.

I'd like to be able to filter the list like you would a contacts list, just by typing, and I came across the textFilterEnabled()

Problem is, I couldn't see how to get it to work with a SimpleCursorAdapter.

Is this even possible?
If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `setTextFilterEnabled()` method doesn't automatically implement filtering, as it doesn't know *what* in your `Cursor` the text should be filtered against.

This [android-developers thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/22b015b031a13bb2) has more details.

Actually, there was a good question asked the other day, which actually is very similar to your question; though it originally was asking how to handle filtering when there is no physical keyboard on a device:

- [How to dynamically update a ListView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/answer-to-making-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android)

Answer (score 24):

For a SimpleCursorAdapter cursor, you only need to use the setFilterQueryProvider, to run another query for your cursor, based on the constraint:

```
m_Adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

  public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "runQuery constraint:"+constraint);
    //uri, projection, and sortOrder might be the same as previous
    //but you might want a new selection, based on your filter content (constraint)
    Cursor cur = managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    return cur; //now your adapter will have the new filtered content
  }

});
```

When a constraint is added (eg. by using a TextView) the adapter must be filtered:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Filter:"+s);
  if (m_slvAdapter!=null) {
    m_Adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. I will try to write a complete article , with source code the next few days.

Comment: Good answer, one of the few that show the runQuery part with cursor - would be even better if you included example of the selection. E.g. selection = FIELD_NAME_TO_FILTER + " like '" + constraint.toString() + "'";

Comment: How should we call a cursor in runQuery if we are using a SQLite database? Using the same databaseHelper instance as the one used for creating the cursor for SimpleCursorAdapter is giving me a "Invalid statement in fillWindow() " error.

Comment: Does `m_slvAdapter` state for `m_Adapter`?

Answer (score 0):

i found this article helpful http://androidcookbook.oreilly.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=CE37400B3E545937B70BE2E9F94E78BB?recipeId=404

basically, you `setTextFilterEnabled(true)` on your listview, and you use `setStringConversionColumn()` and `setFilterQueryProvider()` on your `SimpleCursorAdapter`.