# Filter rows from Cursor so they don't show up in ListView

Tags: android

I have a Cursor that returns rows I use with a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate a ListView.  I would like to filter some of the rows so they don't get displayed in my ListView.  I use the data from the rows elsewhere in my Activity so I don't want to change my SQL to filter them with a WHERE clause.

What is the best way to keep a row from being displaying in my ListView?  Ideally I would check a column in my row and then only add rows to the ListView that satisfy a condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to text filter a listview based on a simplecursoradapter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002607/android-how-to-text-filter-a-listview-based-on-a-simplecursoradapter)

Comment: This answer has some code in it you can copy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766688/filtering-a-cursor-the-right-way

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a `CursorWrapper` and override the `move...()` methods to convert positions in the filtered set (which is what the `ListView` will see) and positions in the actual `Cursor`. Then, use your `CursorWrapper` in the `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks, this helps me a lot! Use it if you need:

```java
private class FilterCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {     
    private String filter;
    private int column;
    private int[] index;
    private int count=0;
    private int pos=0;

    public FilterCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor,String filter,int column) {
        super(cursor);
        this.filter = filter.toLowerCase();
        this.column = column;
        if (this.filter != "") {
            this.count = super.getCount();
            this.index = new int[this.count];
            for (int i=0;i<this.count;i++) {
                super.moveToPosition(i);
                if (this.getString(this.column).toLowerCase().contains(this.filter))
                    this.index[this.pos++] = i;
            }
            this.count = this.pos;
            this.pos = 0;
            super.moveToFirst();
        } else {
            this.count = super.getCount();
            this.index = new int[this.count];
            for (int i=0;i<this.count;i++) {
                this.index[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean move(int offset) {
        return this.moveToPosition(this.pos+offset);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToNext() {
        return this.moveToPosition(this.pos+1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToPrevious() {
        return this.moveToPosition(this.pos-1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToFirst() {
        return this.moveToPosition(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToLast() {
        return this.moveToPosition(this.count-1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
        if (position >= this.count || position < 0)
            return false;
        this.pos = position;
        return super.moveToPosition(this.index[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition() {
        return this.pos;
    }

}
```

https://gist.github.com/ramzes642/5400792

Comment: Can you explain how to use it? please

Comment: Just one thing to add: store the base cursor in the constructor an override the close():

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if (baseCursor != null)
      baseCursor.close();
    super.close();
  }

Comment: 2 other things: (this.filter != "") is incorrect and this.pos is never updated so getPosition() will already return 0. Apart from that this works great.

Comment: @Gábor closing the base cursor seems like a job to be done by the FilterCursorWrapper user and not the wrapper itself, but I see your point if you're not instancing the base cursor itself like so: FilterCursorWrapper(resolver.query(...)); All I mean is it really depends on your usage. Maybe the wrapper pattern states something that might make your suggestion stricter (or not).

Answer (score 2):

In Romans's solution add

```
this.pos = position;
```

in method

```
@Override
public boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
    if (position >= this.count || position < 0)
        return false;
    return super.moveToPosition(this.index[position]);
}
```

Otherwise you will get some problems when using .moveToNext() and .moveToPrevious().