# How to select a specified rows from cursor?

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider

I am working on Android and my intention is to filter out my cursor. The cursor is coming from database and it has some rows. Now I want to skip some rows from cursor by using id column and pass the remaining rows to the listview adapter as cursor.

My code is like checking that the row id is equal to the filtercursor row id then have to skip the row from the presentcursor.

The code:

```
  Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            Provider.CONTENT_URI_DINERS, null,
            DinerColumns.COL_RESERVATION_FROM , null, null);


   c.moveToFirst();
    do{
        String dinerId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DinerColumns.COL_DIN_ID));
        if(isSeatedDiner(dinerId)){

        }

    }while(c.moveToNext());

   private boolean isSeatedDiner(String dinerID){
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    Provider.CONTENT_URI_SEATED,
                    new String[] {"COUNT(*)"  },SeatedDinerColumns.COL_DINE_ID +"="+dinerID , null,
                    null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do
                {
                    String newId =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SeatedDinerColumns.COL_DINE_ID));
                    if(Integer.parseInt(dinerID)==Integer.parseInt(newId))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the data while querying the database.
Or - [Filter rows from Cursor so they don't show up in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027428/filter-rows-from-cursor-so-they-dont-show-up-in-listview)