# Text Filter: strange behavior with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, text, filter

I have a problem with a filter on my listview.
In fact that work pretty well with an IndexAdapter, but not with a SimpleCursorAdapter.

In the following example, if isCursor==false, the filter work pretty well
but if it is == true, the filter does not work!

By the way, the adapter work pretty well.

```
if(isCursor){
    mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stationsCursor, columns, to);
    FilterTextWatcherCursor filterTextWatcher = new FilterTextWatcherCursor(mCursorAdapter);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    this.setListAdapter(mCursorAdapter); 
}

else{
    mIndexAdapter = new MyIndexAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
 R.layout.row_station_picker, elements);
    FilterTextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new FilterTextWatcher(mIndexAdapter);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    this.setListAdapter(mIndexAdapter);
    }

ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

I really do not understand where the problem might come.
For information, my FilterTextWatcher is:

```
public class FilterTextWatcherCursor implements TextWatcher {

 private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter; 

 public FilterTextWatcherCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter adapter) {  
  this.adapter = adapter;
 }

 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 }

 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
   int after) {
 }

 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
   int count) {
  adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
 }

}
```

FilterTextWatcher is quite the same, but I replaced SimpleCursorAdapter with IndexAdapter

Thank a lot for any help...

Comment: Just found a similar question, but I fail to understand the answer!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002607/android-how-to-text-filter-a-listview-based-on-a-simplecursoradapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the FilterQueryProvider instead of the TextWatcher. The following code works fine

```
class XXX extends Activty


class TextQuery implements FilterQueryProvider {
  @Override
  public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence arg0) {
    .... build a new select and provide a cursor
   return cursor;
    }
}


@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 TextQuery textQuery = new TextQuery();
 simpleAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(textQuery);
}
```