# onListItemClick does not work with non-integer id

Tags: android, listview

I am working with a `listview` where the primary key is `text`, not an `integer`. It's actually a **unique url**

It works so far, I even managed to alias the `url column` to `_id` in the `rawQuery()` and the `listview` accepts it happily.

But now I have run into a problem!

`onListItemClick()` returns the id as a long so when I click on an item I just get `0` no matter what.

**Is it possible to obtain the clicked id somehow else?**

Comment: Add a column _id to your db table then the CursorAdapter will work just fine. That seems the most easy.

Comment: @Hermann: The CursorAdapter seems to work perfectly. Everything shows up in the listview as expected. There are no errors. But the id returned from OnListItemClick is always zero because it expects the id to be integer. I don't see why adding an _id column would solve this if the _id is text. Besides, the url column is aliased to _id so from the Adapter's point of view, there is an _id column!

Comment: CursorAdapter (and ContentProvider) expect an column _id with type integer. So if you want the Adapter to behave correctly add that columns _id with type integer. The column with the url can still be the primary key and can still be named id.

Comment: This would definately work, but then I am back to the beginning where I had an integer _id :-) I am new to Android and is exploring the possibilities and I thought that using the url as the _id would be more logical.

Comment: Fighting the framework is not the best way. You should just accept that there has to be a column named _id with type integer. Still you can have an other unique column with type string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to add an field _id to your db. Other wise this may work for you:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Cursor c = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String url = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
}
```

This solution won't work if you use filtering on the Adapter like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2002607/821894). onListItemClick will report the position **after the filtering**.

Comment: I think this works. Except it should be c.getColumnIndex("_id") since the url column is aliased to _id in the query. However, what is filtering? I guess I can still filter my original query using a WHERE clause, right?

Comment: Yes if you filter with sql all is fine. I mean filtering the ListView like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2002607/821894).

Comment: Ah, ok. I tried your solution and it works perfectly. Thanks a million. But one more question: Is it bad practise what I do here, with a non-integer _id column? Should I really go back to the integer _id?

Comment: You will run in problems over and over again if you don't have that _id column with type integer.