# How to get a phone_Number from contacts ListView on onItemClicklistener

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I have created a List of Contacts that's working but when I click on any contact I only get contact Number of 1st Item on the android screen from the ListView.

I want to get Phone Number of clicked contact of that position.
I have searched on web everywhere but didn't get any solution, i am trying to solve this issue for last 13 days but still i am unable to solve this, If anyone can resolve this issue please answer.
Thanks for your help brother/sister!

```java
li.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

TextView txtNummber = li.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)
}
});
```

Comment: if the app is crashing, please post your stack trace. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Can you provide the xml code too, so I can recreate it in Android Studio and try to solve the problem?

Comment: the cursor is your data structure, and position is the element location in your data structure, so use position from inside your setOnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `onItemClick()`, you're using `li.findViewById()`.

But, `onItemClick()` returns `View` as an argument of the clicked item, which is also mentioned in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#public-methods_1).

Hence, try updating it as

`TextView txtNummber = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)`.

Check if it works.

Comment: It Worked. Thanks Bro! can you tell me how to filter contacts and get the searched contact like in our contact's app? I will add 50 bounty more to this question.

Comment: @GopalMeena Further, to filter the list with `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you can check [this code](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/17285/filtering-with-cursoradapter) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5068032/8244632).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Contact Lib](https://github.com/tamir7/Contacts) for any kind of filters. I would recommend you to use `Recyclerview` instead of `ListView`. To implement search in RecyclerView [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40757114/2281175).

`Recylerview` performance is better than `Listview`. Let me know If you have any issue in the implementation.