# Tutorials for simple Android search & what's necessary

Tags: android, search

I have a ListView, as well as a refreshListFromDB(String searchKeywords) method which updates the adapter.

I'd like to implement search, where pressing the search key on my device will pop up the standard search box (and on-screen keyboard if required), and pass the result (onKeyDown) to refreshListFromDB() - or is this considered bad UI design?

Search is a complex beast, so can anyone recommend any bare-bones examples? I don't want to use global QSB, as it's not relavent for my type of app. Do I really need to get into Intents, searchable XML, new activities, content providers etc?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/answer-to-making-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to implement search, where
>   pressing the search key on my device
>   will pop up the standard search box
>   (and on-screen keyboard if required),
>   and pass the result (onKeyDown) to
>   refreshListFromDB() - or is this
>   considered bad UI design?

I don't know about "bad UI design", but the standard search box doesn't do what you say you want it to do.

> Search is a complex beast, so can
>   anyone recommend any bare-bones
>   examples?

I used to have a bare-bones example, but that was before QSB, which added another pile of bones on top of the bones I had. You can still [look at the larger pile of bones here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Search/Lorem/), and the pieces you seek are described in (ahem) a [book](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/).

> Do I really need to get into Intents,
>   searchable XML, new activities,
>   content providers etc?

To use the "standard search box", you need the first two in your list, and possibly the third depending on how you want to do it. I have both reused existing activities and created new ones in my search experiments. You will not need a content provider, though.

Comment: @Eno: If you have the 1st Edition in print, that may be true. I was referring more to the current digital edition -- the Search chapter was moved there a few months ago. Prior to that, you could find the chapter in _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at the [Searchable Dictionary Sample Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html) that comes with the SDK, although I think this does integrate with the Quick Search Box.