# How to filter a listview with and edit box - Android

Tags: android, listview, filter, editbox

I am making a Glossary of legal terms and I would like to be able to narrow the results in the list by typing in an edit box, I have tried finding a solution but none of them have worked for me.

Comment: what you have tried? can you post some code snippets? it helps to find where you are hanged up.

Comment: I have tried Hamy's tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/answer-to-making-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
   lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, Load.getInstance().getTerms()));

I have that and an edit text pointing to a Text watcher
I know I need something in ontextChanged(); but I don't know what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android you don't need a editbox to make that happen. And it's not advised to do so.

Instead just implement Filterable for your Custom Adaptor, and once the user will type in something while views the list it will filter. The onscreen keyboard as usual comes up with holding Menu

Here is a tutorial that has code to [implement Filterable](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/)

Comment: I don't have a custom adapter, nor do I need one for this program, I need the edit text for ascetic purposes, I am writing this program for an iPhone fanatic.

Comment: You will end up writing the filter again, I would recommend doing that 25 line of custom adapter and some additional 10 line for the filterable, and not spending 250 lines in my own filterable method.