# Filtering The ListView(containing contact name and phone number)

Tags: android

I want to filter the ListView which containing both contact name and phone number...

how do i filter the list.....please provide me the code(mainly for the filtering code)

Comment: Youre going to have to provide more information. What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your question is answered here:
[How to make a nice looking ListView filter on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/answer-to-making-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android/1737042#1737042)