# Can anyone please help me correct this code?

Tags: java, android, listview, filter

I get an error at adapter.getFilter().filter(s) in the onTextChanged() function. I was following this - [How to dynamically update a ListView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android) - to creater a filterable List inside a Dialog.

```
public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

private final String[] cityList = {"Seattle", "London"}; private EditText filterText = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);

    /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditBox);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    this.setTitle("Select");
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cityList));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    /** When OK Button is clicked, dismiss the dialog */
}
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing the `adapter` member of your class.

Try changing:

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cityList));
```

to:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cityList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

There is a portion of that article that says

> Turns out that is pretty easy. To run a quick test, add this line to your `onCreate()` call
>
> `adapter.getFilter().filter(s);`
>
> Notice that you will need to save your `ListAdapter` to a variable to make this work - I have saved my `ArrayAdapter<String>` from earlier into a variable called `'adapter'`.

Although that is misleading because the code posted doesn't reflect that change.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for asking such a stupid question, I am new to android. Thanks again

Comment: This community is all about learning, no need to apologize, glad to help.

Comment: How do I destroy the object? I mean where do I call filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher); ?

Comment: You can do it in the `onDestroy()` method of your activity if you like, it really depends on the lifetime of your application and when you want to actually remove the listener.

Comment: This is a custom Dialog class. Should'nt I be removing the listener when I dismiss the Dialog?

Comment: Yes you are correct! Apparently I skimmed over that, take a look into implementing `onStop` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onStop() for doing your cleanup.