# Cannot filter ListView with CursorAdapter subclass

Tags: java, android, listview, filter, cursor

I have a subclass of `CursorAdapter` and I would like to filter my listview. I know that this can be accomplished with an `ArrayAdapter` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android) and that way using a custom `CursorAdapter` does not work for me. I would like to do this with a custom `CursorAdapter`. What should I override and can I have an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [CursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#setFilterQueryProvider%28android.widget.FilterQueryProvider%29) to filter the list. I have an example on [my blog](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/) -- it's in the context of an `AutoCompleteTextView`, but it should work the same way for a `ListView`.