# android- How to use getFilter for CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-cursoradapter

I've a custom listView and a CursorAdapter and search field on optionMenu . 
I used  to have an arrayAdapter and it worked fine but I can't do the same with CursorAdapter .

Could you help me to filter items from cursorAdapter ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [CursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#setFilterQueryProvider%28android.widget.FilterQueryProvider%29). For more details please refer to the answer to the post below. For your ease here is a link to the [blog](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/).

[Answered Question from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559640/cannot-filter-listview-with-cursoradapter-subclass)