# auto search in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I created a list view which extends ListActivity and I have a search field at the top of the page

but I don't know how to write it , I want a search like search contact (type just only 1 char and listview will change, don't have to press any button)

please give me some example code

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216414/using-an-edittext-to-filter-a-simplecursoradapter-backed-listview/5216969#5216969)

Comment: how to adapt it if I use ListActivity

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using a `CursorAdapter` to display the `List`, than you can create a custom `CursorAdapter` which does filtering automatically as you type keys.  The following webpage provides an excellent example of this: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create a AutoCompleteTextView in your Layout,then put this in your class file,

```
AutoCompleteTextView txtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, name_Val);
txtPhoneNo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where name_Val is the String Array that contains "DATA"