# ListView, SimpleCursorAdapter, an an EditText filter -- why won't it do anything?

Tags: android

I'd like to filter a SimpleCursorAdapter-driven ListView with an EditText box right above it. I have the following code, but when I type in the box, nothing happens; the full list continues to display. What am I doing wrong?

```
    mCursor = getDirectoryList(null);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.directory_people_item, mCursor,
            new String[]{
                directoryPeople.LAST_NAME,
                directoryPeople.FIRST_NAME,
                directoryPeople.MIDDLE_NAME,
                directoryPeople.JOB_TITLE},
            new int[]{
                R.id.txtLastName,
                R.id.txtFirstName,
                R.id.txtMiddle,
                R.id.txtTitle} 
    ); 

    ListView av = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPeople);
    av.setAdapter(adapter);
    av.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    av.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    EditText etext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    etext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            ListView av = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPeople);
            SimpleCursorAdapter filterAdapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter)av.getAdapter();
            filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return getDirectoryList(constraint);
        }
    });
```

And here's `getDirectoryList()`:

```
public Cursor getDirectoryList (CharSequence constraint)  {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(
        directoryPeople.PEOPLE_TABLE
    );

    String asColumnsToReturn[] = { 
            directoryPeople.PEOPLE_TABLE + "."
            + directoryPeople.LAST_NAME + "," +
            directoryPeople.PEOPLE_TABLE + "."
            + directoryPeople.FIRST_NAME + "," +
            directoryPeople.PEOPLE_TABLE + "."
            + directoryPeople.MIDDLE_NAME + "," +
            directoryPeople.PEOPLE_TABLE + "."
            + directoryPeople.JOB_TITLE + "," +
            directoryPeople.PEOPLE_TABLE + "."
            + directoryPeople._ID
    };

    if (constraint == null  ||  constraint.length () == 0)  {
        //  Return the full list
        return queryBuilder.query(mDB, asColumnsToReturn, null, null,
                null, null, directoryPeople.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    }  else  {
        return mDB.query(directoryPeople.PEOPLE_TABLE, asColumnsToReturn, "LAST_NAME like '%'" + 
            constraint.toString() + "'%'", null, null, null,
            "CASE WHEN LAST_NAME like '" + constraint.toString() +
            "%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, LAST_NAME");
    }
}
```

I've tried every example and answer I've come across in my searches, but to no avail. It's frustrating, as you can imagine. Thanks in advance for anyone who can help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this way:

```
}  else  {
    String value = "%"+constraint.toString()+"%";

    return mDB.query(directoryPeople.PEOPLE_TABLE, asColumnsToReturn, "LAST_NAME like ? ", new String[]{value}, null, null, null);
}
```

I skipped the last argument because I don't know what it really should do:

```
"CASE WHEN LAST_NAME like '" + constraint.toString() + "%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, LAST_NAME"
```

Have you tried this query in shell in emulator?

Comment: I don't really know what the argument does either. I copied that bit from an example I found and was too tired at the time to figure out what that part did, so I left it in. But if the filter worked and that query was faulty, shouldn't the ListView at least change in some way anyway? I'll try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: It's working with your suggestion! You have no idea how happy I am. I was so close this whole time. Thank you so much!

Comment: What is mDB here? Using the same database helper as the one used for SimpleCursorAdapter is giving me a "Invalid Statement in fillWindow() error"
In my listactivity, I have used an instance of mDbHelper which is my DatabaseHelper. I make a call to c = mDbHelper.fetchAllFriends() followed by a startManagingCursor() in the onCreate of my listActivity.

Should I declare a new instance of mDbHelper for the call in runQuery()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103040/adding-a-text-watcher-to-my-listview-simple-cursor-adapter?noredirect=1#comment26500806_18103040