# AutoCompleteTextView search part of word instead of full word

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView`, and it works nicely, until I add a space to my input. If I had, say, a list of many historical events (Battle of Britain (1940), Battle of the Bulge (1944), [insert lots of battles], Napoleon's fatal march (1812), [insert lots other historical events]).

When I enter "`Battle`" or "`battle`", I get a list of all battles (although it seems there is a max), and when I enter "`britain`", the `"Battle of Britain (1940)"` appears in the results.

However, when I enter `"1940"`, the list is empty, for the same reason that when I enter `"itain"` I don't get any hits. I guess the space is some sort of separator or anchor. If I put `1940` in front of the String (like `"1940 - Battle of Britain"`) and enter "19", I *do* get all the results starting with "19".

Is it possible to have the `AutoCompleteTextView` autocomplete even when there's a character in front of the searched word/phrase/part? (So when I enter "1940", "Battle of Britain (1940)" will be amongst the results?)

Comment: What kind of datasource did you use ?
(like sqlite database)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a custom `Adapter` which implements [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html), in the `getFilter()` method .
 Use `String.contains()` for your requirement

Comment: This seems like it could work. I'll check it probably somewhere in the evening. Thanks.

Comment: How would you implement this though?

Comment: The answer is now outdated.. You can try CursorAdapters now...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322412/listview-simplecursoradapter-an-an-edittext-filter-why-wont-it-do-anything