# How to display (Highlight) value based on another array value in AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Attached is the image in which there is AutoCompleteTextView and i set the ArrayAdapter of Customer Name(String Array).. Now, i want to search a customer name(i have String array of Customer Name) by Customer Address(i have String array of customer address). it means if i type "Ahemdabad" in AutoCompleteTextView it show the list of Customer name whose address is "Ahemdabad"..So, How can i do this?..Any help will be Appreciated.
[image: Customer Name Now adapter]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027261/autocompletetextview-search-part-of-word-instead-of-full-word/13027370#13027370 Check this answer by me.

Comment: you want to search based on customer name or customer address?? write your code also..

Comment: i want to search based on address..

Answer (score 0):

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/myautocomplete"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:completionThreshold="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidAutoCompleteTextView.java

```
package com.AndroidAutoCompleteTextView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class AndroidAutoCompleteTextView extends Activity implements TextWatcher{

AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete;
String item[]={
  "January", "February", "March", "April",
  "May", "June", "July", "August",
  "September", "October", "November", "December"
};

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);

       myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(this);
       myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item));

   }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
  int after) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: i want to display customer name when user enter their address in AutoCompleteTextView..