# Filter listview using editText and simpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, filter, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to filter items in my listView, but its not working. It seems that my code is not responding to the inputted text in my editText.

Here's my SearchActivity class (MainActivity)

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    private DatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper;

      /* Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);
          ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
          myDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

          try {
            myDatabaseHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          myDatabaseHelper.openDataBase();
          Cursor cursor = myDatabaseHelper.queueAll();
          startManagingCursor(cursor);

          String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.KEY_CONTENT};
          int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
          final SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
           new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

          listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
          listContent.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
          listContent.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

          EditText etext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          etext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              }

              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
              }

              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  ListView listContent2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
                  SimpleCursorAdapter filterAdapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter)listContent2.getAdapter();
                  filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
              }
          });

          cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
              public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                  return myDatabaseHelper.getDirectoryList(constraint);
              }
          });

          myDatabaseHelper.close();
```

And this is my getDirectoryList

```
public Cursor getDirectoryList (CharSequence constraint)  {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(DB_NAME);

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_NETWORKING, KEY_HARDWARE, KEY_SOFTWARE, KEY_INTERNET, KEY_TECHNOLOGY};

    if (constraint == null  ||  constraint.length () == 0)  {
        //  Return the full list
            Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query("MY_TABLE", 
             columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            return cursor;
    }  else  {
            String value = constraint.toString()+"%";
            Cursor cursor2 = myDataBase.query("MY_TABLE", columns, "KEY_CONTENT like ?", new String[]{value}, null, null, null);
            return cursor2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322412/listview-simplecursoradapter-an-an-edittext-filter-why-wont-it-do-anything>