# Filtering SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

This code is working properly by showing all the data in database but i have a problem in filtering. I try many code but nothing works , can someone help me out ? thanks

```
 package com.example.dictionary;


    import java.util.List;
    import com.example.dictionary.R;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
        Cursor cursor;
        ListView listView;
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
        Button back, clear;
        List<String> items;
        String get;
        EditText et;
        int textlength = 0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Opening my database and getting all data

```
        Historydb db = new Historydb(this);
        db.open();        
        cursor = db.getword();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,
                    new String[] { "word" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

       listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I set addtextchangelistener in my edittext.

```
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
        // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.

         }
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {


          adapter.getFilter().filter(s);


           }});
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not working because `adapter.getfilter().filter(cs);` does not work directly for SimpleCursorAdapter.
you have to use `adapter.setFilterQueryProvider` first for `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

here is the complete description: [ListView, SimpleCursorAdapter, an an EditText filter -- why won't it do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322412/listview-simplecursoradapter-an-an-edittext-filter-why-wont-it-do-anything)

and this: [Using an EditText to filter a SimpleCursorAdapter-backed ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216414/using-an-edittext-to-filter-a-simplecursoradapter-backed-listview)

Comment: thanks sir adam this thread work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322412/listview-simplecursoradapter-an-an-edittext-filter-why-wont-it-do-anything

Answer (score 2):

Try this....

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
// When user changed the Text
((SimpleAdapter) YourActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);  
}
```

Comment: public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
((SimpleCursorAdapter)MainActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(s);

}
Here sir Anil

Comment: r u getting data from db??

Comment: I already get all the data in db and show all in listview my problem is filtering the data sir.

Comment: Not working sir 
ListAdapter adapter;

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,new String[] { "word" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
((SimpleCursorAdapter)MainActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(s);
}
});