# How to search ListView in Android (Contact's style)

Tags: android, listview, searchable

I have a question regarding application I am building. I have a custom listview defined.  It is backed with the DB data.

I want that I could press search button and that search would appear (the same way as it is done on contacts list), but I have no idea how to handle that. I like search type in contacts a lot because it is changing while typing.

I would be pleased with any advice.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in two steps:

**Build a filterable list** -
[How to dynamically update a ListView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android)

And **[create a search interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)**.

Comment: Great! Will try with search interface. ListView is already built... But do I have to add text watcher (listed in first tutorial)...

_private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher()_

Comment: @M.V. TextWatcher is important to track what the user is writing down.