# Android: ListView making a search Filter

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter, radix

Is there a way to create a search filter over my custom list view which created using BaseAdapter rather than ArrayAdapter, because I have only come across methods that are using ArrayAdapters in there Custom List Views. Follwing is what I have come across[Making a filter using Array Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android)

Comment: Shoud I implement the Filterable interface in my BaseAdapter?

Comment: What are you using, Cursor or Array or something else?

Comment: With what kind of collection?

Comment: @dziobas List collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using List collection then extend ArrayAdapter - it's subclass of BaseAdapter.

Override getView method (In your case just copy your old getView code with little modifications).

Override toString of object that is in your collection and set:

```
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I am doing this right now                                        `class FriendsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable` please tell me what do you mean by overriding the BaseAdapter?

Comment: As I wrote it would be much simpler to override ArrayAdapter: `class FriendsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend>`

Comment: or add android:textFilterEnabled="true" for ListView in layout

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for list view created using base adapter.
I searched a lot but didn't get any satisfactorily solution.Hence I thought to put it up so that in future it might help others.

Here is the code of **history_container.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/filter_text" />
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/historyContainerLayout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code of **history_list_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left|center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="5px"
    android:paddingTop="5px" android:paddingLeft="5px">
    <TextView android:text="@+id/historytext" android:id="@+id/historytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:textColor="#0099CC"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code of **history_schedule.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollItemInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1000dip">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <ListView android:id="@+id/historylist" android:layout_height="1000dip"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry, I am not being able to put the code in correct format.Seems something has changed as there is no  tag anymore which was nice.But for user convenience this is also a good idea to have tab.
Maybe it is my fault that I'm not being able to post in correct format.And seems like we cannot post xml file content..So, think how the layout would have designed.

The activity code is :-

```
package com.testfilter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewStub;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TestFilterListView extends Activity {
    FrameLayout historyContainer;
    ViewStub viewStub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history_container);
        historyContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.historyContainerLayout);
        EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filter_text);
        filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                historyContainer.removeAllViews();
                final List<String> tempHistoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
                tempHistoryList.addAll(historyList);
                for(String data : historyList) {
                    if(data.indexOf((s.toString())) == -1) {
                        tempHistoryList.remove(data);
                    }
                }
                viewStub = new ViewStub(TestFilterListView.this, R.layout.history_schedule);
                viewStub.setOnInflateListener(new ViewStub.OnInflateListener()
                {
                    public void onInflate(ViewStub stub, View inflated)
                    {

                        setUIElements(inflated, tempHistoryList);
                    }
                });
                historyContainer.addView(viewStub);
                viewStub.inflate();

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        setViewStub();
    }


    /********************************************************************************************************/
    private void setViewStub()
    {
        historyList.add("first");
        historyList.add("second");
        historyList.add("third");
        historyList.add("fourth");
        historyList.add("fifth");
        historyList.add("sixth");
        historyList.add("seventh");


        viewStub = new ViewStub(TestFilterListView.this, R.layout.history_schedule);
        viewStub.setOnInflateListener(new ViewStub.OnInflateListener()
        {
            public void onInflate(ViewStub stub, View inflated)
            {

                setUIElements(inflated, historyList);
            }
        });
        historyContainer.addView(viewStub);
        viewStub.inflate();
    }

    /********************************************************************************************************/
    final List<String> historyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String displayName = "";
    ListView historyListView;
    private void setUIElements(View v, List<String> historyLists)
    {

        if (v != null)
        {
            historyScheduleData.clear();
            //historyList.clear();

            historyScheduleData.addAll(historyLists);
            historyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.historylist);
            historyListView.setAdapter(new BeatListAdapter(this));

            registerForContextMenu(historyListView);


        }
    }

    /********************************************************************************************************/
    private static class BeatListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public BeatListAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return historyScheduleData.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.historyData = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.historytext);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.historyData.setText(historyScheduleData.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {

            TextView historyData;
        }
    }

    private static final List<String> historyScheduleData = new ArrayList<String>();


}
```

Comment: here is the url where you can view my blog [link] http://androidsearchfilterlistview.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

[ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) is a child class of BaseAdapter.

Source code for ArrayAdapter is [here](http://netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java). Take a look at it..

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example . Edit and use what you need.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> countryStringList;
private ArrayList<Integer> countryImageList;
private LayoutInflater mInFlater;
// private Bitmap mIcon1;
// private Bitmap mIcon2;
private int layoutID;
private Context context;
// private LayoutInflater mInflater;
public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<String> stringObjects, ArrayList<Integer> imgObjects) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    countryStringList = stringObjects;
    countryImageList = imgObjects;
    layoutID = textViewResourceId;
    mInFlater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // return countryStringList.size();
    return countryStringList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInFlater.inflate(layoutID, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textCountryName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtSelectedCountryName);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgSelectedCountryImage);
        holder.textCountryPosition = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtSelectedCountryPosition);
        // holder.checkBoxListView=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxListView);
        holder.relativeLayoutList = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutListItem);
        holder.checkBoxListView = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSelectedCountry);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        // holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewIcon1)
    }
    holder.checkBoxListView.setTag(position);
    holder.textCountryName.setText(countryStringList.get(position));
    holder.textCountryPosition.setText(position + 1 + "/"
            + countryStringList.size());
    holder.icon.setImageResource((countryImageList.get(position)));
    if (ListViewController.checkStatusList.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("present")) {
        holder.checkBoxListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.checkBoxListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    /*
     * holder.checkBoxListView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new
     * OnCheckedChangeListener(){
     * 
     * @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
     * boolean isChecked) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     * 
     * ListActivityImplementation listActivityImplementation = new
     * ListActivityImplementation(); //show("Checkbox");
     * ListActivityImplementation.countryStringList.remove(position);
     * ListActivityImplementation.countryImageList.remove(position);
     * ListActivityImplementation.lv.invalidateViews();
     * 
     * //ListActivityImplementation.show("Checkbox"); }
     * 
     * }) ;
     */
    holder.textCountryName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            holder.textCountryPosition.setText(position + 1 + "/"
                    + countryStringList.size() + "clicked");
        }

    });
    holder.checkBoxListView
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    MathHelper.showToast(context, buttonView.getTag()
                            + " clicked");
                }
            });
    return convertView;
}
}
class ViewHolder {
TextView textCountryName;
ImageView icon;
TextView textCountryPosition;
RelativeLayout relativeLayoutList;
CheckBox checkBoxListView;
```

}

Comment: Thankyou for this but I want to be know how to use Filterbale interface with the Base Adapter, so that I can filter search my list view