# Android autocomplete and soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-widget

I followed the [AutoCompleteTextView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) exactly. The layout gets wrong when a soft keyboard is involved.

[image]

After tapping inside the dropdown (to select or scroll), the layout is broken:

[image]

I tried various combinations of attributes on the AutoCompleteTextView but none seems to work. I also tried setting windowSoftInputMode. The dropdown always pops up above the textbox, and stays there forever.

In landscape orientation, the layout is OK:

[image]

Is the standard autocomplete useless? Should I use a different one / write my own?

The code I used is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Country" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)  findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: What tutorial have you followed? Please show us some of your code.

Comment: All of the code is in the linked tutorial. I didn't want to duplicate it, but OK I copied it here.

Comment: What device are you running this on?

Comment: HTC Desire, but it behaves the same in the emulator too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using AutoCompleteTextView, I used EditText and a ListView as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android).