# How we can filter the listview when typing in EditText?

Tags: android

I have a ListView and a EditText. I want to be search the name from listview when I type the name in EditText.

Please tell me.

Thanx in advance...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you google around any? I've found that google has taught me more than all my years of college :).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android) SO question for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can [listen for text changes in EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) and run search on every change (I suggest to set a timeout)