# Using a custom ListAdapter for a filtered ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Im using the following code to use a filtered ListView:
[How to dynamically update a ListView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android)

and am trying to make the text color black in the listview. Apparently this can only be done by using a custom adapter, which I had made before. The problem is if i switch to the custom adapter, my ListView doesnt get properly filtered anymore. any ideas? Heres the code:

```
public class OffCampusStopsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] names;

public OffCampusStopsAdapter(Context context, String[] names) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offcampusstopslayout, null, true);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stoplabel);
    textView.setText(names[position]);
    String s = names[position];

    return rowView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I do this way:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LinearLayout alertView;


    //Get the current alert object
    Al al = getItem(position);

    //Inflate the view
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        alertView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        vi.inflate(resource, alertView, true);
    }
    else
    {
        alertView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }
    //Get the text boxes from the listitem.xml file
    TextView alertText =(TextView)alertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlertText);
    TextView alertDate =(TextView)alertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlertDate);

    //Assign the appropriate data from our alert object above

    alertText.setTypeface(font);
    alertDate.setTypeface(font);
    alertText.setText(al.getOfficeName());
    alertDate.setText(al.getAddress());


    return alertView;
}
```