# Android search in a ListView (Android API Level 8)

Tags: android

We are trying to replicate the SearchBar on Android (SDK Level 8). We know that there is a SearchView in Android Level 11 but our devices run on level 8. Is there any widgets or any ways to search a ListView without having to upgrade our devices?

We are trying to mimic the search like the iPhone SDK.

Comment: So you want a EditText where you enter your search term with a ListView below it?

Comment: @Noel : Exactly. And this text will filter the ListView below it, like on the iPhone SDK.

Comment: See this SO post for a very detailed answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android