# How to use search functionality in custom list view in Android

Tags: android, listview, search, baseadapter, custom-adapter

I have created a list view with multiple items in row. I have also created a search box above. I want to implement search functionality on the basis of particular fields of the list. How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655616/how-to-add-search-to-a-list-view-android-sort-items-as-u-type   Your should refer this question-answer it may be helpful to you..

Comment: I got solution check bellow link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475725/android-filter-listview-custom-adapter/23671338#23671338

Answer (score 95):

You have to use model, listview, and customadapter with filtering for this.
I have created a demo for this.

Suppose you have a model named Product, and you are displaying its content in a custom listview where name and price are displayed in a textview. I mean in a custom row having two textviews, and you want to filter the list by one of the field of custom row. Here I have filtered with "name"

**Screenshots:**

Initial

[image: Initial]

Filtered

[image: Filtered]

**Source code**

#### Model

```
public class Product {

    public String name;
    public Integer price;
    public Product(String name, Integer price) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

#### Activity with custom adapter and listview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout llContainer;
    private EditText etSearch;
    private ListView lvProducts;

    private ArrayList<Product> mProductArrayList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    private MyAdapter adapter1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        initialize();



        // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                adapter1.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialize() {
        etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        lvProducts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvOS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("a", 100));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("b", 200));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("c", 300));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("d", 400));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("e", 500));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("f", 600));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("g", 700));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("h", 800));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("i", 900));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("j", 1000));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("k", 1100));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("l", 1200));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("m", 1000));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("n", 1300));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("o", 1400));
        mProductArrayList.add(new Product("p", 1500));


        adapter1 = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, mProductArrayList);
        lvProducts.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }


    // Adapter Class            
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        private ArrayList<Product> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
        private ArrayList<Product> mDisplayedValues;    // Values to be displayed
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> mProductArrayList) {
            this.mOriginalValues = mProductArrayList;
            this.mDisplayedValues = mProductArrayList;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mDisplayedValues.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            LinearLayout llContainer;
            TextView tvName,tvPrice;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                holder.llContainer = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
                holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                holder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.tvName.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).name);
            holder.tvPrice.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).price+"");

            holder.llContainer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mDisplayedValues.get(position).name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                    mDisplayedValues = (ArrayList<Product>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                    notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                    ArrayList<Product> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<Product>();

                    if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Product>(mDisplayedValues); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                    }

                    /********
                     * 
                     *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                     *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
                     *
                     ********/
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        // set the Original result to return  
                        results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                        results.values = mOriginalValues;
                    } else {
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                            String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).name;
                            if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                                FilteredArrList.add(new Product(mOriginalValues.get(i).name,mOriginalValues.get(i).price));
                            }
                        }
                        // set the Filtered result to return
                        results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                        results.values = FilteredArrList;
                    }
                    return results;
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lvProducts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></ListView>    

</LinearLayout>
```

#### row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do I modify your code with my BaseAdapter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506480/how-to-search-within-listview-with-custom-adapter

Comment: @MehulJoisar I was able to modify the code but when I search nothing happens and the `ListView` just disappears.

Comment: @MehulJoisar The link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function) already has the `BaseAdapter` code. I am actually using an `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Hi ! thanks for the code. 
Just one think, i think you must add setAdapter to the listView like this :  
adapter1.getFilter().filter(s.toString());  
lvProducts.setAdapter(adapter1); 
It's doesn't work before, but after I aded it it s work perfectly.

Comment: @serabile: you shouldn't do that inside `onTextChanged` method. Adapter should be set **only once** and then it should just get filtered only as per code I have posted.

Comment: is is possible to implement this using ArrayAdapter instead of baseAdapter bacause I'm having an error in getFilter() function saying there is a clash between this function and the getFilter() in the ArrayAdapter class

Answer (score 7):

Implement filterable in your customadapter class.
[image: listview]
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String names[] = {"Apple","Banana","Kiwi","Oranges","Watermelon"};
String emails[] = {"This is apple","This is banana","This is kiwi","This is oranges","This is watermelon"};
int images[] = {R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.banana,R.drawable.kiwi,R.drawable.oranges,R.drawable.watermelon};

List<ItemsModel> itemsModelList = new ArrayList<>();

ListView listView;

CustomAdapter customAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);


    for(int i = 0;i < names.length;i++){

        ItemsModel itemsModel = new ItemsModel(names[i],emails[i],images[i]);

        itemsModelList.add(itemsModel);

    }

     customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(itemsModelList,this);

    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchView);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            Log.e("Main"," data search"+newText);

            customAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);



            return true;
        }
    });


    return true;

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if(id == R.id.searchView){

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<ItemsModel> itemsModelsl;
    private List<ItemsModel> itemsModelListFiltered;
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(List<ItemsModel> itemsModelsl, Context context) {
        this.itemsModelsl = itemsModelsl;
        this.itemsModelListFiltered = itemsModelsl;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsModelListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemsModelListFiltered.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_items,null);


        TextView names = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView emails = view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.images);

        names.setText(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getName());
        emails.setText(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getEmail());
        imageView.setImageResource(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getImages());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("main activity","item clicked");
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ItemsPreviewActivity.class).putExtra("items",itemsModelListFiltered.get(position)));

            }
        });

        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    filterResults.count = itemsModelsl.size();
                    filterResults.values = itemsModelsl;

                }else{
                    List<ItemsModel> resultsModel = new ArrayList<>();
                    String searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    for(ItemsModel itemsModel:itemsModelsl){
                        if(itemsModel.getName().contains(searchStr) || itemsModel.getEmail().contains(searchStr)){
                            resultsModel.add(itemsModel);

                        }
                         filterResults.count = resultsModel.size();
                            filterResults.values = resultsModel;
                    }


                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                itemsModelListFiltered = (List<ItemsModel>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

}

full tutorial can be found here:
[listview with search and onItemClickListner](https://youtu.be/8QDTiOUOfKQ?sub_confirmation=1)

Comment: BaseAdapter does not have a getLayoutInflater() method

Answer (score 2):

You can set a TextWatcher for your search box and change your Cursor on onTextChanged() on TextWatcher like Codes below :

```
TextWatcher filterNameTextWatcher = new TextWatcher()
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)
        {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before,int count) 
        {
            Cursor FilteredNameList = ZoneCardDBAdapter.instance.CursorFilteredName(s.toString());
            Listadapter.changeCursor(FilteredNameList);


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
        {   
        }
    };

EditText filterTextName = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edtZoneCardNameFilter);
filterTextCPName.addTextChangedListener(filterNameTextWatcher);
```

Answer (score 2):

for this, you first need to add an edittext, where you will type to filter data from the list,

then enable filteration in the list,

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchList);
 adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_row, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Then you need to add `TextChangeListener()` for the edittext,

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                MyActivityName.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);

            }
        });
```

Comment: but when click on the list it throws the wrong position of arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Use  below kind of method.

```
your edit text box.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable theWatchedText) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SearchWithMenuActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchWithMenuActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/expand_layout"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**search_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

**expand_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:elevation="6dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_click"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/srNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/srNo"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/part_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/enter_the_name"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_24" />
            </LinearLayout>

         
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ExpandModel.kt**

```
package com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.models


class ExpandModel(private var name:String,private var expanded:Boolean = false) {

    fun setName(name: String) {
        this.name = name
    }
    fun getName():String{
        return name
    }

    fun setExpanded(expanded: Boolean) {
        this.expanded = expanded
    }
    fun getExpanded():Boolean{
        return expanded
    }
}
```

**ExpandAdapter.kt**

```
package com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.R
import java.util.ArrayList
import android.view.animation.Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF

import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.models.ExpandModel


class ExpandAdapter(private var expandList: ArrayList<ExpandModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpandAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
        val srNo: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.srNo)
        val nameTxt: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.part_name)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.expand_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.srNo.text = (position + 1).toString()
        holder.nameTxt.text = expandList[position].getName()
      
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return expandList.size
    }
}
```

**SearchWithMenuActivity.kt**

```
package com.materialsouk.allcodeapp

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu

import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.adapters.ExpandAdapter
import com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.models.ExpandModel
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


class SearchWithMenuActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var arrayList: ArrayList<ExpandModel>
    private lateinit var adapter: ExpandAdapter
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_with_menu)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        arrayList = ArrayList()
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Meet", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Ankit", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Rushil", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Abhishek", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Modi", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Ghree", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Kirtan", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Ankita", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Soham", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Ganesh", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Dixit", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Ankash", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Parth", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Pranav", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Ankit Sir", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Priya Mem", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Jinal Mem", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Bhumi", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Nidhi", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Hardik", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Mayank", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Kaushik", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Rinku", false))
        arrayList.add(ExpandModel("Mom", false))
        adapter = ExpandAdapter(arrayList)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search)

        val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.maxWidth = android.R.attr.width
        searchView.queryHint = "Search"
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                val freeServiceModelArrayList: ArrayList<ExpandModel> = ArrayList()

                for (i in arrayList) {
                    if (i.getName().lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(
                            newText!!.lowercase(
                                Locale.getDefault()
                            )
                        )
                    ) {
                        freeServiceModelArrayList.add(i)
                    }
                }
                adapter = ExpandAdapter(freeServiceModelArrayList)

                recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                return true
            }
        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}
```