# Search in listview using custom arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android, can any one post the code for the below scenario.

I have set of data like first name, last name, date and id from arraylist to the listview to display, i need to filter it through id and when i click any item in the reduced listview, i need to pass the id so i can display that particular item details seperately in another activity and i have used Custom ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a demo project which is doing exactly what you need,but yes,you need to extend BaseAdapter for this rather than using ArrayAdapter.
here is the whole source code,

[Search on custom adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118309/how-to-use-search-functionality-in-custom-list-view-in-android/14119383#14119383)

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: filter method shows error, what should i have to do to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

A nice tutorial here exactly suits for your requirement. you can go through it

[Listview names search in Android](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/)

Comment: thanks, but i am looking for 4 items to display in each row of listview

Comment: no, i have a arraylist for first name, last name, date and id in that case what can i do

Comment: you can see the example [here](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/image-search-in-the-listview-in-android/). here two arrays images and its names. like this you can implement with your 4 arraylists

Comment: nice but i have all those in one arraylist