# filtering custom adapter IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, filter, custom-adapter

I'm  novice at android.

My custom Adapter cause exception when filtering.

here is my code.
private class DeptAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

```
    private ArrayList<Dept> items;
    private ArrayList<Dept> mOriginalValues;

    public DeptAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Dept> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_listview_2line, null);
        }
        Dept d = items.get(position);
        if (d != null) {
                TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                if (tt != null){
                    tt.setText(d.dept_nm);                            
                }
                if(bt != null){
                    bt.setText(d.dept_cd);
                }
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                items = (ArrayList<Dept>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                if (results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            }
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                ArrayList<Dept> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<Dept>();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Dept>(items); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                }

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    // set the Original result to return  
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                        Dept d = mOriginalValues.get(i);
                        if (d.dept_cd.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()) || d.dept_nm.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                            FilteredArrList.add(d);
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}

class Dept
{
    String dept_cd; 
    String dept_nm; 
    public Dept(String dept_cd, String dept_nm)
    {
        this.dept_cd = dept_cd;
        this.dept_nm = dept_nm;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.dept_nm+ "(" + this.dept_cd +")" ;
    }
}
```

help me anyone....
I can't understand why getView() method was invoked more then items.size()

Comment: Please add complete code of DeptAdapter class and logcat output

Comment: I also want code of the two methods getCount() and getItem(int position)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep in mind that `getView()` will query the size of the items that the `superclass` has, which right now, is what you *originally* passed it when calling the superclass constructor,

```
super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
```

Therefore, the superclass doesn't know that you've changed the size when you have filtered. This means `getCount()` will return the original size of the array, which is understandably larger than your filtered array.

This means You should override the `getCount()` method so you're sure that you're returning the actual valid size:

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
   return items.size();
}
```

You should also override the other methods related to the List operations (such as getting) if you are going to be using them.
Eg:

```
@Override
public Dept getItem (int pos){
     return items.get(pos);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your answer was completely solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this methods for better performance:

```
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return this.items.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `getCount()` method,
look at this [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118309/how-to-use-search-functionality-in-custom-list-view-in-android/14119383#14119383)

I hope it will be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

```
 private ArrayList<Dept> items;
    private ArrayList<Dept> mOriginalValues;

    public DeptAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Dept> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
            this.mOriginalValues=items;  //add this line in your code
    }
```

Comment: `mOriginalValues` is a placeholder while filtering is in place. It doesn't need to hold on to the items from the start.

Comment: if (mOriginalValues == null) { mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Dept>(items); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues                } you see here first use and then initialize bro @A--C

Comment: It's initialized there if it is null, and that's where you save a copy. Assigning in the constructor is a good fail-safe, but the `null` check is already there when you filter for a reason. `this.mOriginalValues=items;` is not needed in the constructor.

Comment: Take a look at the [ArrayAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) source. Search for `init()`. `mOriginalValues` is not instantiated from the beginning. So no, instantiating this object in the constructor won't do much.