# java.lang.String can not be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: android, listview

I am getting this error while doing search functionality with custom listview in android.

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
    FilterResults results) {
        mList = (ArrayList<Details>) results.values;
        DetailsAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        });
```

Comment: Looks like results.values contains String which you are casting to ArrayList<Details>..

Comment: try this => ` mList = (ArrayList<Details>) results;`

Comment: @ved when i am trying to do that I am getting this compilation error.  "Cannot cast from Filter.FilterResults to ArrayList<Details>"

Comment: You are not adding data in mList in proper way.You need to get results.value in separate object then try to add that object values according to your Details class in Details onject then add this Detail object in Arraylist.

Comment: @ved yes you are right. I followed this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118309/how-to-use-search-functionality-in-custom-list-view-in-android . I am able filter the values. but when I backspace the results I am not getting normal list in my listview

Comment: I didn't understand what are you  trying to achieve?

Comment: @ved MyListview is not updating after filtering , when backspace key entered..

Comment: When you press backspace your adapter should get updated with
the default list view for that you need to define a global arrayList and set initilize your adapter inside onCreate method like this.
SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(this);
searchList.setAdapter(searchAdapter);//ListView
Now when you receive data in onQueryTextChanged method like this
ArrayList<ModelClass> arrayListDataDetails = (ArrayList<ModelClass>) response;
notify the adapater for the new dataset change like below
searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @John I tried it.But not working out. :(

Comment: Follow these two example one has source code download buttonhttp://karanbalkar.com/2014/03/tutorial-79-implement-listview-with-search-functionality-in-android/ and http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/
There should not be any problem in implementing it..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example of `ListView` may be it helps :

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ModifyList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
     lv.setAdapter( adapter);
     a=adapter;
     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     search_et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {              
                ModifyList.this.a.getFilter().filter(cs);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you. When my constraint values are null this action if(constraint==null || constraint.length()==0)
             {
              
              
              synchronized(this)
                 {
                  results.values = mOriginalValues;
                  results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                  
                 }
              
              
             } is not performing.