# Usage of PerformFiltering to filter on a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I made an  activity that shows a ListView of recipes that have categories( Strings) and Score (Double) by an Adapter that holds all the data.

I implementing a Dialog that allows you to filter based on choosing the categories.

I looked some examples and all of them use de Filter class and override the method:

```
performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
```

My question is why it explicit asks for a Charsequence parameter, and basically what about if i want to filter by score that is a double datatype.

UPDATE: I'm well aware that there is a search answer posted to filter. But I ask why the method must receive a Charsequence parameter and not any other datatype.

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118309/how-to-use-search-functionality-in-custom-list-view-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118309/how-to-use-search-functionality-in-custom-list-view-in-android).

Comment: I modified the question to clarify the point of interest.

Comment: Your answer is any default type is String . Whenever you get text from a widget it received in String doesn't  mater its int or floating . And String implements  Charsequence .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Android seems to have methods separated for datatype in some cases but not in others.