# How to filter the data in listview.taking data from edit text and filtering data to listview

Tags: android, listview, filtering

I am new to Android.

What A am trying to do is: I have a database file from which I am able to show the data into Android `ListView`. I put an edit text and a `ListView` in the `main.xml` file, as follows, and, in the java file, I'm trying to take a text from the user and show the filtered data in the `ListView`. For that I have tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="1">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/search_box" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="type a word to search"
        android:inputType="text" android:maxLines="1" /><Button android:text="GO" android:id="@+id/bGo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.78"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1" /></LinearLayout>
```

In the java file, I am not able to understand how to search that and show it in `ListView`

```
private EditText filterText = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

DataBaseHelper myDbHelper ;
ArrayList<String> results ;

Button go;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.search);
      myDbHelper  = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
        go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bGo);

        results   = myDbHelper.getdata(); 

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
```

go.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bGo:

        break;

    }
}
```

Well, I am not able to go further because I need to filter the data as the user taps the **Go** button.

Please help me do this.

Thank you,
Moqthar.

Comment: try out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android