# How to get suggestions in listview using Search bar

Tags: android, android-layout

i have created a list view with search bar(edittext) on top of it, i want to use this search bar to pick the items from the list. i have used autocomplete text view which is not able to solve the problem. thanks for ur suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://androidsearchfilterlistview.blogspot.pt/2011/06/android-custom-list-view-filter.html

[How to dynamically update a ListView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android)

What you need is a text filter...

Hope this helps you.