# android simple cursor adapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

i have a list with a SimpleCursorAdapter, this list is made with an arraylist,problem is that i want to add in the list only the value from array that have propriety that "persoane.proprietar=="no" ,this is my code with details

```
    private class ImageAndTextAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Context adContext;

    public int getCount() {
        persNu = persPropNu();
        return persNu;
    }

    public ImageAndTextAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.adContext = context;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) adContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_lista_items, null);
        }
 if (GetObiecte.persoane.get(pos).proprietar.equals("no"))//if put this line in the list will be a blank line if the propriety isn't no,and I don't need it
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textListTopElem)).setText(GetObiecte.persoane.get (pos).nume);
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textListElem)).setText(GetObiecte.persoane.get (pos).judet);
        if (GetObiecte.persoane.get(pos).tipPersoana.equals("fizica")){((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgListElem)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_foto_person);}
        else {((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgListElem)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_foto_person_pj);}
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this value is not changed dynamically then send only the relevant items to the adapter.

if it is changed dynamically you can use a filter like explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android)