# I used setTextFilterEnabled(true) but I don't know where I should write the text

Tags: android

I used

```
setTextFilterEnabled(true)
```

to my listView but no any new thing has been added to my ui , where should I write the text which will filter my data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, you have to implement it yourself...

1. Create your own EditText view which will be used to filter the ListView data.
2. Make your ListView adapter implement the Filterable interface.
3. Watch the EditText for text changes so that you know when to call the `Filter.filter(CharSequence)` method. Use the `EditText.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher)` method to attach a `TextWatcher`.

Comment: no, no, no, all he needs is physical kbd or long press on menu button to show soft kbd

Comment: @pskink I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: another question : OriginalData =  Data;
 FilteredData=(ArrayList<Item>) Data.clone(); do I need to make two copy of my data to make a filter ?

Comment: what adapter are you using?

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush Yes, one for the original data and another for filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

First, chech this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTextFilterEnabled%28boolean%29):

*Enables or disables the type filter window. If enabled, typing when this view has focus will filter the children to match the users input. Note that the [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) used by this view must implement the [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface.*

So, what you need is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android) and possibly [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/Filterable.java#Filterable), for more advanced users.

Cheers :)