# How to filter listview

Tags: android, search, android-listview, filter

I know this is not a new question and there are already lot of similar questions, but my problem is bit different. I am trying to implement search functionality on ListView. i have a listview as following:

```
ListView list;
List<HashMap<String, String>> myDataCollection;
```

I am reading lot of data from XML and creating from it.

```
BinderMyrData bindingData = new BinderMyData(this,  myDataCollection);    
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
// Adding items to listview
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
list.setAdapter(bindingData);
/*** Enabling Search Filter * */
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                    //Some code to be added no clue..
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
```

I know I have to add some code there in onTextChanged. I have no clue what code... Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android/1737042#1737042) topic?

It explains perfectly well how to apply search functionality to your ListView.

Long story short:

add **`bindingData.getFilter().filter(cs);`** inside your **`onTextChanged()`** method

But it is the most convenient way if you work with standard `ArrayAdapter<E>`, and you are using some kind of weird `List<HashMap<String, String>> myDataCollection;` adapter as hashmapped list. If this won't work, you should really consider changing your adapter to some more friendly one, like `ArrayAdapter<E>`.

Comment: Thanks I already have read the topic you mentioned. getFilter doesn't work with Hashmap. I think I have to change entire code to use ArrayAdapter.