# not getting the result in after filter the listview

Tags: android, listview, textwatcher

i just create an app in which i m getting back the same contact list as it is saved,data is not getting filter,i want to get the data that user enter in the autocompletetextview,it get match with with the listview and give the result,but in this code m getting back whole of the listview..how to compare it,and display only resultant data...?? please suggest me with some clue. 
**MainActivity**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,
            OnItemSelectedListener {
        SearchView mSearchView;
        AutoCompleteTextView searchText;
        ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();

        MyAdapter ma;


        String[] cellArray = null;


        String contacts;


        ListView lv;

        String phoneNumber, name;

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        List<String> arrayListNames;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());
            searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

            ma = new MyAdapter();

            searchText.setThreshold(1);
            searchText.setAdapter(ma);

            lv.setAdapter(ma);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);





        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_main, menu);
            MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
                System.out.println(".............." + ma.mCheckStates.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

                {
                    if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                        // phno0.add(name1.get(i).toString());
                        phno0.add(phno1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                                + name1.get(i).toString());
                    }

                }

                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

                finish();

                break;


            case R.id.action_search:

                searchText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //String text_To_search= searchText.getText().toString().trim();
                searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //System.out.println(".............." + ma.mCheckStates.size());
                        for(int i=0;i<name1.size();i++){

                        if(searchText.getText().toString().trim().equals(name1.get(i).toString()))

                        ma.getFilter().filter(s);
                             /* //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), name1.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            phno2.add(name1.get(i) + phno1.get(i));*/
                        }
                        //lv.setAdapter(ma);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int count, int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });

                break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                ma.toggle(position);

    //
        }

        public void getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {
            mPeopleList.clear();
            Cursor phones = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                    null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                            + " ASC");
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                phoneNumber = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                name = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                System.out.println(phoneNumber);

                name1.add(name);
                phno1.add(phoneNumber);


            }

            phones.close();

        }

        class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements  Filterable,
                CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
            public SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
            // public ListFilter listFilter;
            LayoutInflater mInflater;
            TextView tv1, tv;
            CheckBox cb;

            MyAdapter() {
                mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }









            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View vi = convertView;
                if (convertView == null)
                    vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                tv.setText(name1.get(position));
                tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));
                cb.setTag(position);

                cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

                return vi;

            }

            public boolean isChecked(int position) {

                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

            }



            @Override
            public Filter getFilter() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Filter filter = new Filter() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                        arrayListNames = (List<String>) results.values;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                        ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();

                        // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.

                        constraint = searchText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                        for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++) {
                            String dataNames = name1.get(i);
                            if (dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))  {
                                FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                            }
                        }

                        results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                        results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
                        //Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());

                        return results;
                    }
                };

                return filter;
            }
        }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two steps:

Build a filterable list - [How to make a nice looking ListView filter on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android)

And [create a search interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).

Comment: i already read that.,problem is my data is not getting filter