# implement search on a custom listview

Tags: android, search, listview

i have a `listview` and `EditText` field and i wanna implement search, but my `listview` is a custom `listview` populated with array of objects of class Item. And when i press key whole `listview` gone so i guess the problem is that it cannot match char with object of class Item that's why there is no results when i press a key.
this is my code

```
 filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextfilter);
 filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    m_items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    phoneList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    phoneList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     this.m_adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row,m_items);


     phoneList.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);

    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

        m_adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

    }

};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}
```

any help how to get it works

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement. I have used a custom Filter.

```
    ArrayList<PostData> mPostingData = null;//arraylist of class items
    ArrayList<PostData> mTemp = new ArrayList<PostData>();//temporary arraylist of class items
    ArrayList<PostData> mOri = new ArrayList<PostData>();//Original arraylist
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    search= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
     search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                         mCustomListView.getFilter().filter(s);
                         mCustomListView.notifyDataSetChanged();

         }

         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
             int after) {


           }

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           }
          });
```

POJO Class

```
     class PostData {
String mID; 
String mPostedBy;
String mTitle;
String mMessage;
String mImageUrl;
String mVideoUrl;
String mType ;
boolean me=false;
    }
```

Custom List View with Filter method overriden. Search based on mTitle of POJO Class

```
  class CustomListView extends ArrayAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

private Bitmap mIcon1;
private Bitmap mIcon2;
private Bitmap mIcon3;
PostData mp ;

public  CustomListView(Context c)
{
     super(c, 0);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.text_icon);
    mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.image_icon);
    mIcon3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.video_icon);
}   

public int getCount() {

    if(mPostingData!=null){
        return mPostingData.size();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

 public void setData(ArrayList<PostData> mPpst) {   
    mPostingData = mPpst;//contains class items data.
}

 @Override
 public Filter getFilter() {
     return new Filter() {
         @Override
         protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
             if (results != null && results.count >= 0) {
                 setData((ArrayList<PostData>) results.values);//if results of search is null set the searched results data
             } else {
                 setData(mOri);// set original values
             }

             notifyDataSetInvalidated();
         }



        @Override
         protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
             FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
             if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                 constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                 ArrayList<PostData> foundItems = new ArrayList<PostData>();
                 if(mTemp!=null)
                 {
                 for(int i=0;i<mTemp.size();i++)
                 {
                    //If mTitle contains the string entered in Editext 
                     if (mTemp.get(i).mTitle.toString().contains(constraint)) {
                         foundItems.add(mTemp.get(i));

                     }
                     else
                     {

                     }
                 }
                 }
                 result.count = foundItems.size();//search results found return count
                 result.values = foundItems;// return values
             } 
             else
             {
                 result.count=-1;// no search results found
             }


             return result;
         }
     };
 }
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ViewHolder holder;
    ///int type = getItemViewType(arg0);
     Log.i("Aru","get View");
    if(mPostingData == null ){

        return null;
    }
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewimg, null);
                convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                // we want to bind data to.
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.ll=(LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvid);
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texttitle);
                holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvst);
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llimage);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            mp = mPostingData.get(position);

            String title = mp.mType;
            if(mp.mTitle!=null && Name.equals(mp.mPostedBy )){
                title = mp.mTitle+" "+title;
                //holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                holder.ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listbkgme);
                holder.text.setText(title);
            }
            else if(mp.mTitle!=null && Name!=mp.mPostedBy)
            {
                title = mp.mTitle+" "+title;
           holder.text.setText(title);
            }


            if(mp.mMessage!=null && Name.equals(mp.mPostedBy )){
                holder.ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listbkgme);
                holder.text2.setText(mp.mMessage);

            }
            else if(mp.mMessage!=null && Name!=(mp.mPostedBy))
            {
                holder.text2.setText(mp.mMessage);
            }


            if(mp.mImageUrl!=null ){

                holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon2);
            }else if(mp.mVideoUrl!=null){
                holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon3);
            }else{
                holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
            }
       return convertView;
}
 class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    TextView text2;
    ImageView icon;
    LinearLayout ll;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}
 }
```

Modify the above according to your requirements. I have tested the code and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make a data class like this

```
package ali.search;
    public class Data {

        public Data() {

        }

        int id;
        private String JobTitle;
        private String Department;
        private String Locationn;
        private String JobRole;



        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getJobTitle() {
            return JobTitle;
        }

        public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
            JobTitle = jobTitle;
        }

        public String getDepartment() {
            return Department;
        }

        public void setDepartment(String department) {
            Department = department;
        }

        public String getLocation() {
            return Locationn;
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            Locationn = location;
        }

        public String getJobRole() {
            return JobRole;
        }

        public void setJobRole(String jobRole) {
            JobRole = jobRole;
        }
    }
```

Make Activity class like this

```
package ali.search;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    String[] jobtitles = { "Android Developer", "Tester","iOS Developer",
             };
    String[] departments = { "android", "testing", "iphone" };
    String[] locations = { "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Noida" };
    String[] jobRoles = { "develop android based apps", "test mobile apps",
            "develop iphone based apps" };

    private ListView listViewSearch;
    private EditText editSearchView;

    private SearchAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Data> sortedItems = new ArrayList<Data>();
    private ArrayList<Data> OrignalItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        listViewSearch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSearch);
        editSearchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        OrignalItems = getListOfType();
        sortedItems.addAll(OrignalItems);
        adapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this, sortedItems);
        listViewSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
        editSearchView.addTextChangedListener(searchTxtChangeListener);

    }

    private ArrayList<Data> getListOfType() {

        ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setJobTitle(jobtitles[i]);
            data.setDepartment(departments[i]);
            data.setLocation(locations[i]);
            data.setJobRole(jobRoles[i]);
            data.setId(i);
            dataList.add(data);
            dataList.add(data);// dulicate entry 
        }

        return dataList;

    }

    private TextWatcher searchTxtChangeListener = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            int textlength = editSearchView.getText().length();
            sortedItems.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < OrignalItems.size(); i++) {
                if (textlength <= OrignalItems.get(i).getJobTitle().length()) {
                    if (editSearchView
                            .getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) OrignalItems.get(i).getJobTitle().subSequence(0,
                                            textlength))) {
                        sortedItems.add(OrignalItems.get(i));

                    }
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    };
}
```

Finally this the custom adapter

```
package ali.search;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SearchAdapter extends  BaseAdapter{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Data> list;
    LayoutParams params;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Data> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (vi == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);            
            holder.txtDepartment = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtDepartment);          
            holder.txtLocation = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);          
            holder.txtJobRole = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtJobRole);            
            holder.layoutRelative = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.layoutRelative);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(list.get(position).getJobTitle());
        holder.txtDepartment.setText(list.get(position).getDepartment());
        holder.txtLocation.setText(list.get(position).getLocation());
        holder.txtJobRole.setText(list.get(position).getJobRole());


        return vi;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout layoutRelative;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDepartment;
        TextView txtLocation;
        TextView txtJobRole;

    }
}
```

It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In custom listview,you must create a Filter method in Adapter.