# how to set json parsed data in a listview and then adding search functionality in it

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am new to android and want to parse json data in a listview and then add search functionally to it, but I don't know how to add search.

The Java class is:

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {


// url to make request
private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/quick/punk.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CUSTOMER = "Customer";
private static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE = "customer_code";
private static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME = "customer_name";
private static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_MOBILE = "customer_mobile";
private static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS = "customer_address";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray Customer = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        Customer = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CUSTOMER);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < Customer.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = Customer.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String customer_code = c.getString(TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE);
            String customer_name = c.getString(TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME);
            String customer_mobile = c.getString(TAG_CUSTOMER_MOBILE);
            String customer_address = c.getString(TAG_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS);




            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE, customer_code);
            map.put(TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME, customer_name);
            map.put(TAG_CUSTOMER_MOBILE, customer_mobile);
            map.put(TAG_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS, customer_address);


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE, TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME,TAG_CUSTOMER_MOBILE,TAG_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS}, new int[] {
                    R.id.code, R.id.name,R.id.mobile,R.id.address});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

The xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<!-- Main ListView 
     Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
-->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

What I want is that when a user types something in the textbox, it should be searched in the data that is there in the list. Can any one tell me how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Custom List adapter to display items in listview. Display a editText on the top.
For custom Listview http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/.

For searching listview.
[How can I filter ListView data when typing on EditText in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645209/how-can-i-filter-listview-data-when-typing-on-edittext-in-android/13172848#13172848).

For custom search
[implement search on a custom listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383943/implement-search-on-a-custom-listview/13110015#13110015). I suggest you to go with search on custom listview with filters.

Edit

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText 
 android:id="@+id/search"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity Class

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 ArrayList<NewData> mTemp=new ArrayList<NewData>();
 ArrayList<NewData> mPostingData=new ArrayList<NewData>();
 ArrayList< NewData> mOri = new ArrayList<NewData>();

    Myadapter ma;
    EditText search;

    NewData nd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                 // Add your Json Parsed Data here
                // each item from json add it to hash map in NewData class. Arraylist of 0 contains jsondata of customer1
                nd=new NewData();

                nd.newDatacus.put(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE, "i"+i);
                nd.newDatacus.put(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME, "a"+i);
                nd.newDatacus.put(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_MOBILE, "number");
                nd.newDatacus.put(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS, "address");
               mOri.add(nd);
            }

         ma= new Myadapter(MainActivity.this);
       mPostingData=mOri;
       mTemp=mOri;
        ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        search= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
         search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                             ma.getFilter().filter(s);
                             ma.notifyDataSetChanged();

             }

             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                 int after) {


               }

               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               }
              });


    }



class Myadapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater mInflater;


     public void setData(ArrayList<NewData> mPpst) {   
            mPostingData = mPpst;//contains class items data.
        }

     @Override
     public Filter getFilter() {
         return new Filter() {
             @Override
             protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                 if (results != null && results.count >= 0) {
                     setData((ArrayList<NewData>) results.values);//if results of search is null set the searched results data
                 } else {
                     setData(mOri);// set original values
                 }

                 notifyDataSetInvalidated();
             }



            @Override
             protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                 FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                     constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                     ArrayList<NewData> foundItems = new ArrayList<NewData>();
                     if(mTemp!=null)
                     {
                     for(int i=0;i<mTemp.size();i++)
                     {

                         if (mTemp.get(i).newDatacus.get(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE).toString().contains(constraint)) {
                             System.out.println("My datas"+mTemp.get(i).newDatacus.get(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE).toString());
                             foundItems.add(mTemp.get(i));

                         }
                         else
                         {

                         }
                     }
                     }
                     result.count = foundItems.size();//search results found return count
                     result.values = foundItems;// return values
                 } 
                 else
                 {
                     result.count=-1;// no search results found
                 }


                 return result;
             }
         };
     }
    public Myadapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mPostingData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ViewHolder holder;


            if(mOri == null ){

                return null;
            }
                    // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
                    // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
                    // by ListView is null.
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
                        convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                        // we want to bind data to.
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        holder.t1=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        holder.t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        holder.t3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

                        convertView.setTag(holder);
                    } else {
                        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                        // and the ImageView.
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }
                    holder.t1.setText(mPostingData.get(position).newDatacus.get(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE).toString());
                    holder.t2.setText(mPostingData.get(position).newDatacus.get(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME).toString());
                    holder.t3.setText(mPostingData.get(position).newDatacus.get(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_MOBILE).toString());
                    return convertView;
        }
}
 class ViewHolder
 {
TextView t1,t2,t3;
}
}
```

list.xml to be inflated in custom list adapter

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

NewData Class- Holds all data in hashmap

```
   public class NewData {
public static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE = "customer_code";
public static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME = "customer_name";
public static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_MOBILE = "customer_mobile";
public static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS = "customer_address";

   Hashtable newDatacus=new Hashtable();

    public NewData()
    {

        newDatacus.put(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_CODE,new String());
        newDatacus.put(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS,new String());
        newDatacus.put(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME,new String());
        newDatacus.put(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_MOBILE,new String());
        newDatacus.put(NewData.TAG_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS,new String());




    }
}
```

Modify so that you add your json data in the for loop. I have made search criteria here customer id. You can change this according to your needs. This code is tested and it works. Hope someone can give a better code. Hope this helps you.

Comment: look when we do parsing of json data into listview,then we give id of list view as (android:id="@android:id/list")..but for searching from the list i need id of list like   (lv= (listview)findviewbyid(R.id.(*)))in place of of star i need listview id..

Comment: for searching on listview you just have to compare/filter your listview data according to what is entered in the edittext. Display new data according in listview based on user input in edittext.

Comment: if your listview is displaying list of names, then get the data as and when user types in editext compare it with the listview data and notify your adapter of the changes and display items accordingly.

Comment: my reqiurement is do i get id of list."@android:id/list" how do i resolve this problm.

Comment: Why do you want id of list to make a search? Listview displays data provided by the adapter. All you have to do is provide data based on search and notify the adapter that data is changed.

Comment: and i have alreadly done it with adapter also,,but when i start typing in the edittext,,the app is unextected stop.

Comment: post it here. if i can't help someone will. It will help others who are in the same situtation