# Unable to display listview data after filter

Tags: java, android

I have a listview adapter filter that is correctly filttering my inputted text with the use of a like statement.

The issue I am having is that when my app loads, all the data is displayed in the listview. When the filter is applied it correctly filters to the supplid text, **what I cant do is have it so that once the edittext is blank again (i.e the search string is deleted), all of the data is redisplayed in the listview.**

The following screenshots display the issue:

Loaded list:

[image]

Filter text 'a'. Apple displayed as expected:

[image]

Issue: When the 'a' is deleted, the listview is not reloaded.

[image]

Code for the filter:

```
        itemNameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);

    showItems.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    itemNameEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
     {


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }


     });


    getCons = new DBHandlerShop (this, null, null);

     cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider()
    {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint)
        {

            getCons.open();
            return getCons.getChanges(constraint.toString());


        }

    });
     showItems.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

getChanges method:

```
public Cursor getChanges(String constraintPassed) {

        String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWSHOPID, KEY_ITEMSHOP, KEY_ITEMNUM, KEY_ITEMPRICE};
        Cursor c = null;
         if(constraintPassed == "" || constraintPassed.length() == 0)
         {
             c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLESHOP, columns, null, null, null, KEY_ITEMSHOP + " ASC", null); 


         }

         else
         {

            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLESHOP, columns, KEY_ITEMSHOP + " LIKE'" + constraintPassed + "%'", null, null, null, KEY_ITEMSHOP + " ASC", null);

         }

        if( c != null)
            {
                c.moveToFirst();
                //return c;

            }
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: add cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in on textchange method to refresh listview

Comment: you are probably not refreshing your listview when edittext is blank

Comment: @Raghunandan I added the DataSetChanged on the textChanged method and have the same issue it dosent refresh

Comment: what are you returning from the filter when edittext is blank. When edittext is blank display whole set of original values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357866/search-bar-in-application/15358474#15358474. Probably the answer in the link may help you.

Comment: @Raghunandan I have an if statement that if it is blank, all of the results should be returned in the cursor as shown above

Comment: Your code looks fine to me so I'm not sure what is happening. But never do this `constraintPassed == ""` _always_ use `equals()`, in this case `isEmpty()` or `length() == 0` will do by itself.

Comment: is your databse query correct when edittext is blank. if ur returning right values then it should display all data in listview

Comment: @Sam please answer the question as you were correct. Changing the values to the equals worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you are using:

```
if(constraintPassed == "" || constraintPassed.length() == 0)
```

You should never use `==` for Strings, you must use `equals()`.
But in this case you can just use `constraintPassed.length() == 0` or:

```
if(constraintPassed.isEmpty())
```

(Please read [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1267661) to learn the difference between `==` and `equals()`.)