# Android filter listview data from json

Tags: android, json, listview

I want to filter a listview data from json. this is what I've tried so far:

```
  wsSearch = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.wsSearch);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    wsSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher (){

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //BAPTISMAL_SONG.this.adapter2.getFilter().filter(cs); 

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayTemplist= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            String searchString = cs.toString();//wsSearch.getText().toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++)
            {
                String currentString = arraylist.get(i).get(BAPTISMAL_SONG.TAG_TITLE);
                if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentString))
                {
                    arrayTemplist.add(arraylist.get(i));
                }
            }
            adapter2 = new ListViewAdapterBaptismal(BAPTISMAL_SONG.this, arraylist);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter2);

        }

    });
```

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696917/implementing-search-filter-for-data-from-server-retrieved-as-json) but when I tried to enter something on my edittext it does not filter. What am I doing wrong in here? ANy help is truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're always using the `arraylist` collection. Also, I would recommend to add the filter logic to `afterTextChanged` method.

Comment: @gunar what do u mean I'm using the arraylist?

Comment: I meant that you perform some stuff and putting data in `arrayTemplist`, but in the end you're creating the adapter with a different object: `arraylist`

Comment: @gunar Oh i see, so what can I do to make this filter?

Comment: What is `arraylist` holding? Same type of data as `arrayTempList`?

Comment: ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist; it's holding the json from my server

Comment: Provided the answer ... It should be the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
adapter2 = new ListViewAdapterBaptismal(BAPTISMAL_SONG.this, arraylist);
listview.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

with:

```
adapter2 = new ListViewAdapterBaptismal(BAPTISMAL_SONG.this, arrayTemplist);
listview.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

in your `onTextChanged` method. The way it is right now you're performing the filter, but you're using the old collection, not the one where you have put the filtered content.

**EDIT**: To perform the filtering if the length of the string is at least 2, then you could have this:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //BAPTISMAL_SONG.this.adapter2.getFilter().filter(cs); 
    String searchString = cs.toString();//wsSearch.getText().toString();
    if(searchString.length() != 2) {
        adapter2 = new ListViewAdapterBaptismal(BAPTISMAL_SONG.this, arraylist);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter2);
        return;
    }
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayTemplist= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++)
        {
        String currentString = arraylist.get(i).get(BAPTISMAL_SONG.TAG_TITLE);
        if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentString))
            {
                arrayTemplist.add(arraylist.get(i));
            }
        }
    adapter2 = new ListViewAdapterBaptismal(BAPTISMAL_SONG.this, arrayTemplist);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

Comment: wow it works, but how can I limit to 2 letters to display the records?

Comment: I am not sure I understand **limit to 2 letters** ... you want to perform the filter only of the string length is at least 2? Also, don't forget to upvote.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, I don't know how do you call that, if I'm not mistaken it's like the function of an autocompletetextview, when I would type only 2 letters, it filters the suggested data

Comment: Edited the answer ... Please check if that helps, even though I consider I answered to your question already :P

Comment: I tried ur updated answer buddy, but unfortunately it's not getting the results

Comment: `when I would type only 2 letters, it filters the suggested data` ... editing the answer again

Comment: You said in the first comment that this works ... Didn't you make some changes that corrupted the initial behavior?