# Edit Text which gives suggestions from the list view under it

Tags: android, listview, autocomplete, android-edittext

In my Android app, I have this screen where the top part is a search box kind of thing and below it there is a `ListView`. Now the requirement is that when a user starts typing something in the search box I have push up items from the list view which match that pattern.

I have thought of using Auto Complete TextView, but that does not help because the items displayed must be in the list view itself where they can be clicked. They just need to be pushed up the list when they match the pattern of text typed in the Search box above.

How to achieve this ?
Please Help.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645209/how-can-i-filter-listview-data-when-typing-on-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **addTextChangedListener** in EditText to get user interactin with EditText and update the ListVIew using `notifyDataSetChanged();`. Try to use **Handler**

Comment: thanks deepak. It worked, but I did not use handler. Can u tell me where can I find some sample code