# how should i filter corrosponding checkbox with the string

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-arrayadapter

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,contactList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

there is a EditText on the top of my ListActivity which is use to filter the contact list. But when i use the code below to filter.

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);

            }
 }
```

Only the string value associated with each item get filtered out but the checkbox associated with it remains same.

Example. Say I have 3 contacts "A", "B", and "C". when I open this ListActivity and select "A". Now when I search for contact "C"(by entering "C" in the search box) contacts get filters out and I can see the contact "C" on the top. But, it shows that it has already been selected. Actually, its not...because the checkbox associated with "C" was never shorted out...and the current checkbox seems to be associated with "C" is of contact "A".

What should i do to get the filtering synchronized?

[image: after A is selected]m[image: when filter in action].png

Comment: You could try making your own custom adapter to help you out. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645209/how-can-i-filter-listview-data-when-typing-on-edittext-in-android

Comment: @AJcodez thanku for replying.....even i am thinking to do it using custom adapter....

Comment: Yeah what you are describing sounds like it shouldn't happen. Possibly make your own layout for each item? It should be removing the whole item from the list with filtering.

Comment: thanks again..... I will check that out.. now working on another part of the app....will come back on it latter....and might need your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was hit by this issue as well, solved it by extending `ArrayAdapter` with my own custom adapter, and overriding `getView`, in which i set each view as checked/unchecked according to my unfiltered list.

This is my getView code:

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            CheckBox view = (CheckBox) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            MyObject object = getItem(position);

            view.setChecked(object.selected);
            view.setOnClickListener(MyClass.this);

            return view;
        }
```

I've also had MyClass implement `onClickListener`, to toggle the selected state of the clicked MyObject and call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`