# How to implement a Search input box with list view to search items from the list view using QML

Tags: qml

I am trying to implement a Search input box with list view to search any item from the list view using QML. 
I have implemented the TextInput box and the ListBox, now I need to implement code for the communication between the InputBox and the listbox, so that when I write a letter in the InputBox, the items from the listBox will appear.

Any suggestions for this implementation is highly appreciated. Please provide your thoughts on this.

Thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645209/how-can-i-filter-listview-data-when-typing-on-edittext-in-android/13172848#13172848. Search on ListView and Custom ListView. Is this what your looking for??

Comment: Yes, I am looking for that, but in Qt/QML not in Android. The link you provided is for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should expose a `text` string property in your `TextInput` Item, and handle its changes by updating the list in your `ListBox`.

Something like this:

```
TextInput {
  id: textInput

  onTextChanged: {
    // Update the filter for the ListBox
    listBox.filter(text)
  }

}

ListBox {
  id: listBox
}
```

Comment: Fine, but how to write the code for filter the text in the list view. Could you please explain a little bit.

Comment: Well, this depends on how you implemented your ListView... AND is a different question. You should add a new question.

Comment: I know that onTextChanged, I have to implement the sorting, that's what I asked in the forum, because there is not inbuilt sorting function available for ListView.

Comment: This post is related to another post. Please answer. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466986/sorting-listbox-items-as-per-the-input-provided-by-user-in-qt-qml)