# QML ListView filter items

Tags: listview, filter, qml

I have a ListView table. I want to add some filter buttons to hide/show items of this table based on item type. The easiest way is set visible property of the item delegate. However, hidden items are still counted in listView.contentHeight, or listView.visibleArea.heightRatio. As a result, these values change when scrolling and affect the height and position of the scrollbar, it collapses, expands, jumps in no order.

Other issue is that in the listView, if an item is selected, there is no way to know its index, for instance it looks like it is in the second place in the table but actually its index is higher because of the invisible items. It could be nice if the invisible items are not counted at all.

Please help how to solve this issue. Thank you all.

```
ListView{
  id: listView
  delegate: itemdelegate
}

Component{
  id: itemdelegate
  Item{
    visible: model.type === filteredType ? true: false
  }
}
```

Comment: To anyone arriving to this question, a very good way to filter items in a QML ListView is using the DelegateModel as the ListView model as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941043/is-it-possible-to-show-only-certain-indexes-of-a-qml-listview)

Answer (score 3):

Append items to your display model dynamically, f.e.

```
filterButton.onClicked:{
    for(var i = 0; i < myListModel.count;i++)
    {
        if(myListModel.get(i).desiredProperty == "desiredValue")
            myDisplayModel.append("prop1":"val1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I had this solution earlier but performance wise your way takes more time to clear and populate the list view model (and so the table items), resulting GUI freezing. I have tried a performance test and my mentioned way took significantly shorter time.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing the data comes from the C++ side of your application, the proper way of doing this is to use Qt's [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) on your model.

If you are not already using one, here is the doc about [using C++ Models with QML Views](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html)

Comment: It might work but since the data comes from QML, your proposal is not applicable then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out to use VisualDataModel QML item for ListView filtering and it works very nice.

Comment: Any example of this?

Comment: you can search for VisualDataModel sample. This is an old thread but i will try to update the code with sample at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Using DelegateModel we can make use of DelegateModelGroup to filter and show a subset of the ListModel. In the following example, I implement FilterDelegateModel based combining DelegateModel with an Array-like-filter property so that we can easily define a filter:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        Label { text: qsTr("Search") }
        Frame {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            TextEdit {
                id: searchTextEdit
                width: parent.width
            }
        }
        Label { text: qsTr("States (count:%1)").arg(filterDelegateModel.count) }
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            clip: true
            model: FilterDelegateModel {
                id: filterDelegateModel
                model: states
                filter: search ? model =>  model.state.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1 : null
                property string search: searchTextEdit.text.toLowerCase()
                onSearchChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
                delegate: Frame {
                    id: frame
                    property int visibleIndex: DelegateModel.visibleIndex
                    width: ListView.view.width
                    background: Rectangle {
                        color: visibleIndex & 1 ? "#e0e0e0" : "#d0d0d0"
                        border.color: "#c0c0c0"
                    }
                    RowLayout {
                        width: parent.width
                        Text {
                            text: (visibleIndex + 1)
                            color: "grey"
                        }
                        Text {
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            text: model.state
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: states
        ListElement { state:"California" }
        ListElement { state:"New York" }
        ListElement { state:"Las Vegas" }
        ListElement { state:"Seattle" }
        ListElement { state:"Texas" }
    }
}

//FilterDelegateModel.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQml.Models 2.15
DelegateModel {
    property var filter: null
    onFilterChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: allItems
            name: "all"
            includeByDefault: true
            onCountChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: visibleItems
            name: "visible"
        }
    ]
    filterOnGroup: "visible"
    function update() {
        allItems.setGroups(0, allItems.count, [ "all" ] );
        for (let index = 0; index < allItems.count; index++) {
            let visible = !filter || filter(allItems.get(index).model);
            if (!visible) continue;
            allItems.setGroups(index, 1, [ "all", "visible" ]);
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(update)
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAALLHiclVZtb9MwEP7eX3HLBEq0krVIfAkMJMoGkwpjA4EQ2gcvuabWHLtzHMa09b9zdtIsb2WbI6Wt77nzPefz4%2FJspbSBU3Na8PgSXobTVyPemgtnShqtRD5onLMbVZgcptb2laUItyOgMVOiyGRprabsYDJeKp2HCy5EBCumUZqeMWM65TKPYDqpbXN2gQJuweBfE8FV%2Fl373jdkOl56Aaxr2JFmGTbWK11tEm7JnzwxywiMLrAF%2BU5RDxNuOp528CSC3C20AfUg12XUkk3ofrUw9%2Bmt%2F8%2FHMIM5%2BLEqpImeTQMvCKkUPmVuUH9AgSkBPqsERegwTeZznpsfHK%2BfTr4B%2BYQ8XZoBTCz4amA6s7lEcNRPcEslB6j0cFXQ3FWjZy0jbPYE3pVwOHhbOYbOLzRqrq5Rz1iOfhBymeDfk4VfOgWwc3AAL6YQgSxEP4GVVivU5oZS0Fym1VLdNgjt1rXX6UVSsuzR2ZLJFIn%2FqQljJsScUtR%2BsUros%2B%2BVVOWJBtu5VU5rH7TWHLg08Ifn%2FELgsa1CBO1GatoGI1XdvekvcqBXv8k344LFl6mm7qT0zjA2RFxso2BHrISi7WymAc9hShvr7eLEPh7tk7ebTOzjbY1zoXSCOqzCebvxxD7D%2BPXg7Jm67unVlmJsPerNYRvlP6HsKE%2B%2F3yK%2FB9N%2BSzTHhmKq8WZ7PYY5PjKvR6jGMJXGEXxiZv3Z9kxXRMu37cqu3jjFbouHhR0KzGjTSHOdMfJmTPCF0pIzr6OjPegX0tVfSl8%2BCJyzHH7Q6cofRJIwGCPwQRzt1n209Wg9Gu3vD%2BhteJWJzt38pMs8E6GLUxmGtLyWlD9M1zJcC6iSZVYPS51VhxXd7r9r4q3VPlpzpz%2FtllKsY4NZ%2B0aQpH90FMjWPglcxqJI8P3NB1ywQgxdaUrO7B36OGlej5%2BW7OZEb0u4snudpj5377K2J9IF74IXhYwNVxLKFP2g%2Be%2BqKlGYo3HOuT8Z38%2B6%2Fwxj%2BF3WC84heF270kEAX6ABd1XCAUxeV1%2FfdAJU83t7QYe39a5SJf%2BdkgXc3VV8%2FDpMisZ3MYLQ6UUjDVe%2FBfg7VaCA1E4aLgtsYwaYuohjmNYEx%2FeVg%2FPGGk39mCk6AdJquW2HbEUctvbC%2Bh9djwGB)

There's a performance problem with the above implementation in that every change we do: changing the filter, adding new records to the source ListModel will cause all records to be rescanned again. This becomes problematic if your have a large number of records in the ListModel (say, over 1000). To deal with such issues I have a more comprehensive implementation of FilterDelegateModel that incremental updates https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-toolkit/blob/main/FilterDelegateModel.qml

Answer (score -2):

You can set the width/height according to the filter condition.
For example:

```
Rectangle {
    width: condition?100:0
    height: condition?100:0
}
```