# Is it possible to show only certain indexes of a QML listview?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

Is it possible to show only certain indexes or a range of indexes in QML listviews?

I have a listmodel that has a bunch of info that I am reusing. Would it be possible to have a list showing, for example, only indices 5 to 8?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It would be interesting to present a pure QML approach to the problem. This is **not** the shorted path, for sure, but it is a solution.

The approach is based on the [`DelegateModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html) available in the `models` QML module. It reads in the documentation:

> The DelegateModel type encapsulates a model and the delegate that will
>   be instantiated for items in the model.
>
> It is usually not necessary to create a DelegateModel. However, it can
>   be useful for manipulating and accessing the modelIndex when a
>   QAbstractItemModel subclass is used as the model. Also, **DelegateModel
>   is used together** with Package to provide delegates to multiple views,
>   and **with [DelegateModelGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodelgroup.html) to sort and filter delegate items**.

`DelegateModel` is really a powerful type with a lot of functionalities (see the linked documentation for details). Two key properties of `DelegateModel` are [`groups`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html#groups-prop) and [`filterOnGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html#filterOnGroup-prop). The former is basically a list of `DelegateModelGroup` which defines the items to be filtered or not. The latter is used to apply a specific filter, i.e. choose a specific `DelegateModelGroup` contained in `groups`, by simply setting the property to the name of the chosen group.

Note that referring to `VisualDataModel` or `DelegateModel` is the same since the first is provided for compatibility reasons (the same applies to `VisualDataGroup` w.r.t. `DelegateModelGroup`).

Summing up, it is possible to filter a model in full QML in this way:

1. Create a `model` as a source of filtered models
2. Feed the `model` to a `VisualDataModel`/`DelegateModel`
3. Define a `VisualDataGroup`/`DelegateModelGroup` (or more than one) - `includeByDefault` set to `false` to avoid automatic addition of **all** items from the original model
4. Define policies to populate the groups
5. Set `filterOnGroup` to the chosen group
6. Set the view model to the `VisualDataModel` model

In the next example, for simplicity, I just populate the group once, during the `Component.onCompleted` event handler. As said, policies should be chosen and that's depends on the specific use case.

In the example only the items with `key` role equal to `0` are added to the group `key0` which is the one shown in the `ListView`. The checklist described above is highlighted in the code.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("DelegateModel test")
    width: 200
    height: 350
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: displayListView
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 5
        //
        model: displayDelegateModel             // 6
    }

    ListModel {                                 // 1
        id: myModel
        ListElement { vis: "One"; key: 0; }
        ListElement { vis: "two"; key: 1; }
        ListElement { vis: "Three"; key: 0; }
        ListElement { vis: "Four"; key: 0; }
        ListElement { vis: "Five"; key: 1; }
        ListElement { vis: "Six"; key: 1; }
        ListElement { vis: "Seven"; key: 0; }
    }

    VisualDataModel {
        id: displayDelegateModel

        delegate:  Rectangle {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            height: 25
            color: "steelblue"

            Text {
                text: vis
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                font.bold: true
                font.pixelSize: 20
            }
        }

        model: myModel                          // 2

        groups: [
            VisualDataGroup {                   // 3
                includeByDefault: false         // NECESSARY TO AVOID AUTOADDITION
                name: "key0"
            }
        ]

        filterOnGroup: "key0"                   // 5

        Component.onCompleted: {                // 4
            var rowCount = myModel.count;
            items.remove(0,rowCount);
            for( var i = 0;i < rowCount;i++ ) {
                var entry = myModel.get(i);
                if(entry.key == 0) {
                    items.insert(entry, "key0");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example, i have one question though.
items.insert(entry, "key0")  inserts the "key0" property to the item so that it can be sorted on later again?

Comment: hey uhm, i just realized... is this delegateModel new? Because there was no support for treemodels in QML, and in the docs i am reading that it supports treemodel operations

Comment: forgot to add the "@name" :D,, hmmm its not working,, nevermind this comment

Comment: Depends on the naming but it is supported since a long time ago. The "key0" acts like a filter: everything is inside that group can be sorted out from the full list.

Comment: Is there a way to do a simple filter by role?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You need to override `QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptRow` method.

```
MyFilterModel::filterAcceptsRow ( int source_row, const QModelIndex & source_parent ) const
{
  if ( source_row > 5 && source_row < 8 )
    return true;

  return false;
}
//...
MyFilterModel *filter = new MyFilterModel();
filter->setSourceMoldel( yourSourceModel );
view->setModel( filter );
```

Answer (score 3):

You could accomplish that by setting the delegate visibility to false on certain conditions:

```
  Grid {
    anchors.fill: parent
    rows: 4
    columns: 5
    spacing: 5
    Repeater {
      model: 20
      delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 50
        height: 50
        visible: index >= 5 && index <= 8 // show only certain indices
        Text {
          anchors.centerIn: parent
          text: index
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

It will have some overhead of creating hidden items in memory thou, so not optimal if you deal with very large models and showing only small portions of them.

Comment: and how to detect scrolling request to change the index?

Comment: @DrlSherifOmran if you bind to an expression that references properties with change notifications, if their values change, it will cause visibility to be reevaluated automatically. Although for scrolling you have ready to use components.

Comment: This worked a treat! I used this to create paging. Something like `visible: currentPage == 1 ? index < 6 : index >= 6` where `currentPage` is a root property. No caveats. Just worked.

Comment: @HeathRaftery - there are better options for that, you can use filtering so that you don't end up with scores of invisible objects just taking up memory.

Comment: Scores? Better? Taking up memory? None of those seem to apply my application, so perhaps not in this case?

Comment: @HeathRaftery for a few items don't bother. If you have dozens, hundreds or thousands... that's a different story.

Answer (score 1):

This is another answer based on `DelegateModel` in this answer, I have implemented a generalized wrapper called `FilterDelegateModel` that:

1. Implements two DelegateModelGroups `"all"` and `"visible"`
2. The "all" property group will contain all records from your source model
3. The "visible" property group will contain a subselection of records
4. Also, I implement `role`, `from` and `to` property (for property binding)
5. Whenever any property changes it calls an `update()` method
6. Whenever `update()` is called, the "all" group is rescanned and only matching/filtered records are placed in the "visible" group

To demonstrate how to use `FilterDelegateModel` I put 8 animals into a ListModel with a corresponding `"aid"` role and then I use a `ListView` to visualize it. I control the `"from"` and `"to"` properties via a `RangeSlider`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: FilterDelegateModel {
                model: animals
                role: "aid"
                from: range.first.value
                to: range.second.value
                delegate: Frame {
                    background: Rectangle {
                        color: index & 1 ? "#f0f0f0" : "#e0e0e0"
                    }
                    width: ListView.view.width
                    RowLayout {
                        width: parent.width
                        Text {
                            text: `${aid} ${animal}`
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Text { text: range.first.value.toFixed(1) }
            RangeSlider {
                id: range
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                from: 1
                to: 8
                first.value: 3
                first.onValueChanged: filterDelegateModel.update()
                second.value: 8
                second.onValueChanged: filterDelegateModel.update()
            }
            Text { text: range.second.value.toFixed(1) }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: animals
        ListElement { aid: 1; animal: "Aardvark" }
        ListElement { aid: 2; animal: "Bear" }
        ListElement { aid: 3; animal: "Cat" }
        ListElement { aid: 4; animal: "Dog" }
        ListElement { aid: 5; animal: "Eagle" }
        ListElement { aid: 6; animal: "Fruitbat" }
        ListElement { aid: 7; animal: "Goat" }
        ListElement { aid: 8; animal: "Hedgehog" }
    }
}

//FilterDelegateModel.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQml.Models 2.15

DelegateModel {
    property string role
    property real from: 0
    property real to: 100
    onRoleChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
    onFromChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
    onToChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: allItems
            name: "all"
            includeByDefault: true
            onCountChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: visibleItems
            name: "visible"
        }
    ]
    filterOnGroup: "visible"
    function update() {
        allItems.setGroups(0, allItems.count, [ "all" ] );
        for (let index = 0; index < allItems.count; index++) {
            let item = allItems.get(index).model;
            let visible = item[role] >= from && item[role] <= to;
            if (!visible) continue;
            allItems.setGroups(index, 1, [ "all", "visible" ]);
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(update)
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?code=import%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Layouts%201.15%0A%0APage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ColumnLayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anchors.fill%3A%20parent%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anchors.margins%3A%2010%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Label%20%7B%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Select%20Range%22)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Frame%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RowLayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%7B%20text%3A%20range.first.value.toFixed(1)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RangeSlider%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20range%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20from%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20to%3A%208%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20first.value%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20second.value%3A%208%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%7B%20text%3A%20range.second.value.toFixed(1)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Label%20%7B%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Fruits%22)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListView%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillHeight%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3A%20FilterDelegateModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3A%20animals%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20role%3A%20%22aid%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20from%3A%20range.first.value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20to%3A%20range.second.value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20delegate%3A%20Frame%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background%3A%20Rectangle%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20index%20%26%201%20%3F%20%22%23f0f0f0%22%20%3A%20%22%23e0e0e0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20border.color%3A%20%22%23d0d0d0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20ListView.view.width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RowLayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20parent.width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%60%24%7Baid%7D%20%24%7Banimal%7D%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20ListModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20animals%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListElement%20%7B%20aid%3A%201%3B%20animal%3A%20%22Aardvark%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListElement%20%7B%20aid%3A%202%3B%20animal%3A%20%22Bear%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListElement%20%7B%20aid%3A%203%3B%20animal%3A%20%22Cat%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListElement%20%7B%20aid%3A%204%3B%20animal%3A%20%22Dog%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListElement%20%7B%20aid%3A%205%3B%20animal%3A%20%22Eagle%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListElement%20%7B%20aid%3A%206%3B%20animal%3A%20%22Fruitbat%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListElement%20%7B%20aid%3A%207%3B%20animal%3A%20%22Goat%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListElement%20%7B%20aid%3A%208%3B%20animal%3A%20%22Hedgehog%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2FFilterDelegateModel.qml%0Aimport%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQml.Models%202.15%0A%0ADelegateModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20property%20string%20role%0A%20%20%20%20property%20real%20from%3A%200%0A%20%20%20%20property%20real%20to%3A%20100%0A%20%20%20%20onRoleChanged%3A%20Qt.callLater(update)%0A%20%20%20%20onFromChanged%3A%20Qt.callLater(update)%0A%20%20%20%20onToChanged%3A%20Qt.callLater(update)%0A%20%20%20%20groups%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DelegateModelGroup%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20allItems%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22all%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20includeByDefault%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onCountChanged%3A%20Qt.callLater(update)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DelegateModelGroup%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20visibleItems%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22visible%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20filterOnGroup%3A%20%22visible%22%0A%20%20%20%20function%20update()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20allItems.setGroups(0%2C%20allItems.count%2C%20%5B%20%22all%22%20%5D%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20index%20%3D%200%3B%20index%20%3C%20allItems.count%3B%20index%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20item%20%3D%20allItems.get(index).model%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20visible%20%3D%20item%5Brole%5D%20%3E%3D%20from%20%26%26%20item%5Brole%5D%20%3C%3D%20to%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!visible)%20continue%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20allItems.setGroups(index%2C%201%2C%20%5B%20%22all%22%2C%20%22visible%22%20%5D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Component.onCompleted%3A%20Qt.callLater(update)%0A%7D%0A)

Note that the weakness of this implementation are:

1. It only performs well on a small number of records, since every time the source `ListModel` changes we apply the filter to the entire list
2. We only support a simplified filter, i.e. `>= from and <= to`
3. If there are large number of records (i.e. >= 1000), the UI may block whilst it is applying a filter.

To address these problems, I have a more generalized implementation https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-toolkit/blob/main/FilterDelegateModel.qml which:

1. Reacts to incremental updates to your source model by only filtering the newly added records
2. Filters your records in 50ms chunks separated by Qt.callLater() to ensure that the UI/UX is not blocked for too long (helpful for filtering >= 1000 records)
3. Allows for Javascript Array-like-filtering with a generalized filter function