# QML ListView default behavior when model is updated

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have the following `ListView` that always show the beginning of the list when the `QStringListModel` is updated by using `setStringList` on the C++ side.

For example, the user can scroll up and down in the view, and when the model is updated, the view goes back to the beginning of the list.

How to disable this behavior ?

Also i need the view to display exactly X items ( 2 in my example ) at once. The view is not in itself scrollable ( `interactive: false` ) but the user can navigate the list by clicking up and down `Button`'s somewhere in the UI.

Is there a suitable approach for that ? ( following [Is it possible to show only certain indexes of a QML listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941043/is-it-possible-to-show-only-certain-indexes-of-a-qml-listview) )

**EDIT :** i have added 2 functions for the "up/down" problem and it seems to work as expected but i am still interesting to know if there is a better way.

Thank you.

```
        ListView {
            id: view
            anchors.top = parent.top
            anchors.left = parent.left
            readonly property int visibleItems: 2
            readonly property int itemHeight: 20
            height: visibleItems * itemHeight
            width: 100
            clip: true

            model: listModel // a QStringListModel

            delegate: Rectangle {
                border.width: 1
                border.color: "black"
                height: view.itemHeight
                width: 100
                Text { text: model.display }
            }

            interactive: false

            function up() {
                var currentTopIndex =  indexAt(view.width / 2, contentY)

                if (currentTopIndex !== -1) {

                    var newTopIndex = currentTopIndex - view.visibleItems

                    if (newTopIndex >= 0)
                        view.positionViewAtIndex(newTopIndex, ListView.Beginning)
                 }
            }

            function down() {
                var currentTopIndex =  indexAt(view.width / 2, contentY)

                if (currentTopIndex !== -1) {

                    var newTopIndex = currentTopIndex + view.visibleItems

                    if (newTopIndex < view.count)
                        view.positionViewAtIndex(newTopIndex, ListView.Beginning)
                 }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `contentY` to its previous value after the model data changed?

Comment: I think your problem might be solved in a better way, by actually inserting/removing the rows instead of resetting the model. Is this a possibility in your code?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside your `ListView`, any time the model data changes you reset the `contentY` property. Here I'm assuming `contentX` doesn't change.

```
property real previousContentY

Connections {
    target: model
    onModelAboutToBeReset: view.previousContentY = view.contentY
    onModelReset: view.contentY = view.previousContentY
}
```

And you probably want to also add `snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem` if you want to show only certain items.

Comment: It does not work even though the slot are actually called

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be to wrap `ListView` with an external `Flickable` that will be responsible for the scroll.

This solution does not require to manually reset the previous `ListView` `contentY`, since the scroll position is not dependant on the `ListView` itself anymore.

Here is a basic working example:

```
Button {
    id: button
    text: 'change model'
    onClicked: view.aModel = !view.aModel
}

Flickable {
    anchors.top: button.bottom
    width: parent.width
    height: 100
    interactive: true // the scroll will be managed by this external Flickable
    contentHeight: view.contentHeight
    clip: true

    ListView {
        id: view
        property bool aModel: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        interactive: false // deactivate scroll on the internal Flickable
        model: aModel
               ? ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"]
               : ["b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"]
        delegate: Text {
            width: parent.width
            height: 20
            text: modelData + index
        }
    }
}
```