# Link two qml files

Tags: qt, qml

I know you must be confused by the title but I had anything title in mind that could describe my issue, I have a `qml` files that contain kinda of different rectangle organized by listModel, my idea is to have a main file that contains all rectangles which are in other different files .
seeig I had put many code I'll do it simple :

**button1.qml**

```
ListModel
    {
        id : lightSalon
        ListElement
        {
            name : "Principal"
            lightId : 11
        }
        ListElement
        {
            name : "Secondaire"
            lightId : 12
        }
       
    }

Rectangle{

    Eclairage{
        textEclairage : (nbOfEclairage>1) ? lightSalon.get(1).name : ""
        bEclairage : bEclairage2Salon
    }
}
```

**button2.qml**

```
ListModel
    {
        id : lightSalon2
        ListElement
        {
            name : "Principal"
            lightId : 11
        }
        
       
    }

Rectangle{

    Eclairage{
        textEclairage : (nbOfEclairage>1) ? lightSalon2.get(1).name : ""
    bEclairage : bEclairage2Salon2
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

I want this file to have all the `Eclairage` on the 2 files

Comment: I don't really understand what you need. Do you want to have access to two lists? Or combine 2 list into single one?

Comment: @folibis no i want that my main.qml file combine the listModel , je te donne un exemple i have 2 rooms  that have 4 lighting  and a kitchen has one lighting so i want the main file combine all the lighting in the house

Comment: This question is confusing, because (1) it declares a ListModel, but does not use it (i.e. no application of Repeater, ListView, or anything), (2) you name your source files `button` but they look nothing like buttons, (3) You define an Eclairage inside a Rectangle but do not elaborate what this is (the Rectangle has none of the Rectangle properties set).

Comment: Probably your application has a broken architecture, that's why your question is unclear. First of all `ListModel` is a data provider for some view and should not be used explicitly. You probably want a single list that includes all the items. If you need some kind of sorting/filtering take a look at `QSortFilterProxyModel`. Another solution as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941043/is-it-possible-to-show-only-certain-indexes-of-a-qml-listview) answer is using `DelegateModel`/`DelegateModelGroup`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you require, but, I declared a combined ListModel with both of your light assets within. I've added a `room` element so we can select between rooms as well as provided (p,q,w,h) being the x-position,y-position,width,height of each light assets.

```
// AssetsModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ListModel {
    ListElement {
        room: "Salon"
        name: "Principal"
        lightId: 11
        p: 20; q: 20; w: 100; h: 100; c: "red"
    }
    ListElement {
        room: "Salon"
        name: "Secondaire"
        lightId: 12
        p: 200; q: 100; w: 100; h: 100; c: "green"
    }
    ListElement {
        room: "Salon2"
        name: "Principal"
        lightId: 11
        p: 150; q: 50; w: 100; h: 100; c: "orange"
    }
}
```

I implemented a `DelegateModel` that allows us to supply a room filter to the delegate model, e.g.

```
// FilterDelegateModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQml.Models
DelegateModel {
    property string role
    property string filter
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup { name: "all" },
        DelegateModelGroup { name: "new" },
        DelegateModelGroup { name: "visible" }
    ]
    // ...
}
```

That way, you can use the `FilterDelegateModel` to render your light assets in either a `ListView` or a `Repeater`. Here's a full working example:

```
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Label { text: "Room" }
        ComboBox {
            id: roomCombo
            model: [ "Salon", "Salon2" ]
        }
        Label { text: "Design" }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            color: "lightgray"
            Repeater {
                model: FilterDelegateModel {
                    model: AssetsModel { }
                    role: "room"
                    filter: roomCombo.currentText
                    Rectangle {
                        x: p
                        y: q
                        width: w
                        height: h
                        color: c
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Label { text: "Details" }
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            model: FilterDelegateModel {
                role: "room"
                filter: roomCombo.currentText
                model: AssetsModel { }
                delegate: RowLayout {
                    width: ListView.view.width
                    Label { Layout.preferredWidth: 100; text: room   }
                    Label { Layout.preferredWidth: 100; text: name   }
                    Label { Layout.preferredWidth: 100; text: lightId }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)