# How to restrict EditText to only specified characters in android?

Tags: android

I want to restrict my EditText to only specific characters like (a-z,A-Z,0-9,space,.and some other).

If the user tries to enter some other characters beyond the list,it should not be displayed in edittext.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why is this even closed? He is asking how to do something which is not ambiguous at all. The only ambiguity I can see here is that there is more than one way of achieving what he wants, but that's the case of 90% of the questions here (90% was made up).

Comment: Absolutely, this is a real question, clearly defined and well understood. It was incorrectly marked as closed by @Andrew Barber. The answers to this question are also most valuable. I have given both this question and the comment above +1.

Comment: @MarioS I've changed the close reason to a more accurate one.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
     public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
          for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
              if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
                  return ""; 
                  } 
           } 
           return null; 
     } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Check [How can I filter ListView data when typing on EditText in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1645209/1341006)

Comment: can you please explain how to use this?

Comment: input filter I think is better than textwatcher in this case +1

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution for you....

Just add the characters to the string which you want to `allowed`

```
    final String allowed = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit001);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            char currentChar = s.charAt(start);
            System.out.println(currentChar);
            if(allowed.contains(Character.toString(currentChar)))
            {
                //Nothing to do
            }
            else
            {
                editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().substring(0, editText.getText().toString().length()-1));
                int position = editText.length();
                Editable etext = editText.getText();
                Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

`yourEditText.addTextChangedListener()`

then, you see if the user input match your restriction or not, and choose what characters to be display.